# O que é a assinatura de um método?

Tags: c#, java, c++, orientação-a-objetos, método

Uma assinatura do método, ou função comum, ou construtor é composta por seu nome + quantidade de parâmetros + tipo dos parâmetros?

Comment: Eu resolvi separar as perguntas que tratavam de dois assuntos diferentes quando o usuário Leonardo fez uma [outra pergunta sobre o assunto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34685/construtores-padr%c3%a3o-java). Eu pedi para ele separar mas ele não voltou mais ao site. Então está aqui a parte separada.

Comment: Concorda que aqui cabem as tags [tag:independente-de-linguagem] e [tag:terminologia]?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A assinatura é o jeito de identificar um método de forma única. Em linguagens onde vários métodos podem ter o mesmo nome, você precisa ter uma outra forma de evitar a ambiguidade. O compilador precisa saber qual dos métodos com mesmo nome você está chamando. Então você precisa se valer de informações extras disponíveis no método para tomar uma decisão. O mais comum é analisar os parâmetros. Se todos os parâmetros forem iguais, você tem o mesmo método, se apenas um desses parâmetros for diferente, você tem um método diferente. É possível que o retorno e outras informações possam ser analisadas também, mas isto não é comum já que podem trazer alguns problemas. Por igual entenda que a ordem também é importante.

Java é uma das linguagens que foram pelo caminho seguro de analisar só os parâmetros. Isto é comum acontecer. C# também foi por este caminho. C++ optou por utilizar o tipo do retorno também em algumas situações.

Em tese seria possível utilizar qualquer informação disponível, até o nome do parâmetro. Em geral isto seria uma má ideia, mas nada impede que uma linguagem utilize. É ela quem vai determinar o que é bom ou não para ela. Java e C# provavelmente se valeram dos problemas encontrados na utilização em C++ para evitar tanta flexibilidade.

Vejamos exemplos em Java (quase todos funcionam bem em C# também):

```
int FazAlgumaCoisa() { // faz alguma coisa aqui }

int FazAlgumacoisa(int valor) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
```

Estes métodos têm o mesmo nome mas são diferentes, eles provavelmente executam alguma coisa (pelo menos) ligeiramente diferente (embora isto não seja obrigatório, apenas seria esquisito fazer exatamente o mesmo), mas não muito diferente, afinal, se isto ocorresse, não justificaria o mesmo nome. Há uma chance razoável do primeiro apenas chamar o segundo passando um parâmetro *default* (mas não precisa ser assim). Ex.:

```
int FazAlgumaCoisa() { FazAlgumaCoisa( 0 ); }
```

E agora vejas estes métodos:

```
int FazAlgumaCoisa(int valor1) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }

int FazAlgumaCoisa(int valor2) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
```

Eles possuem a mesma assinatura ou não?

Possuem! Você teria um conflito se declarasse ambos. A análise só considera o tipo dos parâmetros, não seu nome.

Mas eu só coloquei a declaração dos métodos, não mostrei a declaração das classes. Eu considerei que estes métodos são da mesma classe. Isto quer dizer que você pode ter métodos que aparentam ter a mesma assinatura, mas no fundo a assinatura é diferente. Veja:

```
int FazAlgumaCoisa() { // faz alguma coisa aqui }

int FazAlgumaCoisa() { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
```

Isto é possível? Bem, é se os métodos pertencerem a classes diferentes:

```
class Exemplo1 {
    int FazAlgumaCoisa() { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
}
class Exemplo2 {
    int FazAlgumaCoisa() { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
}
```

Desta forma é válido. O que muita gente não entende é que métodos de instância possuem um parâmetro implícito (escondido). Podemos chamar ele de `this`. No fundo, por baixo dos panos, estas classes são montadas assim:

```
class Exemplo1 {
    int FazAlgumaCoisa(Exemplo1 this) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
}
class Exemplo2 {
    int FazAlgumaCoisa(Exemplo2 this) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
}
```

percebeu que a assinatura é diferente? Se usarmos o método que tinha um `int` como parâmetro explícito ficaria assim:

```
class Exemplo1 {
    int FazAlgumaCoisa(Exemplo1 this, int valor) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
}
class Exemplo2 {
    int FazAlgumaCoisa(Exemplo2 this, int valor) { // faz alguma coisa aqui }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Signature101.cs).

Algumas pessoas vão falar no número de parâmetros do método. Mas é óbvio que se o número de parâmetros for diferente os tipos são diferentes, afinal leva-se em consideração todos os tipos, então no mínimo você estaria comparando um tipo determinado com nada, o que claramente é algo diferente. É óbvio que `xxx(int, int)` é diferente de `xxx(int, int, int)`.

Lembrando que `string, int` é diferente de `int, string`. A ordem tem relevância.

Outros elementos podem fazer diferença na assinatura dependendo da linguagem. Veja mais detalhes sobre o C# na resposta do dcastro.

Veja a [especificação da linguagem Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) (a pergunta original falava em Java).

A especificação do C# mais atual pode ser encontrada para [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou [acesso direto](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (versão mais antiga). Em sua resposta o dcastro citou as partes mais relevantes dela.

A especificação do C++ [deve ser comprada](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard). Um [rascunho](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) está disponível gratuitamente.

Comment: Se for uma linguagem como Lua ou alguma outra de tipagem fraca, como eu devo considerar a assinatura de um método/função?

Comment: Lua não tem métodos propriamente, mas se pensar em funções então a assinatura normalmente é só o nome mesmo. Duas funções com mesmo nome no mesmo escopo não podem ser desambiguadas usando outros critérios.

Answer (score 13):

A resposta varia conforme a linguagem. No caso de C#, a assinatura de um método é composta por:

- o nome do método
- o numero de parâmetros genéricos (ex: `T`)
- o numero de parâmetros
- os modificadores dos parâmetros (ex: `out`, `ref`)
- os tipos dos parâmetros.

O tipo de retorno, *generic constraints* (ex: `where T: IDisposable`) e o nome dos parâmetros não fazem parte da assinatura.

Relativamente a *overloading*:

- os tipos `object` e `dynamic` sao considerados iguais;
- os modificadores `this` e `params` sao ignorados;
- as assinaturas de dois métodos pertencentes ao mesmo tipo não podem diferir apenas pelos modificadores `ref` e `out`. Ou seja, os seguintes 2 métodos não podem coexistir no mesmo tipo:

  ```
  void Method(out i);
  void Method(ref i);
  ```

  Mas podem ser declarados em tipos diferentes na mesma árvore hierárquica (*method hiding* e *overriding*).

Da seccao 1.6.6 da especificacao:

> The signature of a method must be unique in the class in which the method is declared. The signature of a 
>   method consists of the name of the method, the number of type parameters and the number, modifiers, and types 
>   of its parameters. The signature of a method does not include the return type.

Da seccao 3.6:

> Although `out` and `ref` parameter modifiers are considered part of a signature, members declared in a single 
>   type cannot differ in signature solely by `ref` and `out`
>
> For the purposes of singatures, the types `object` and `dynamic` are considered the same. Members declared in a 
>   single type can therefore not differ in signature solely by `object` and `dynamic`.

No entanto, apesar de outros elementos nao fazerem parte da assinatura dum metodo (ex: nome dos parametros), todos eles contribuem para a API pública e alterá-los é considerado *breaking change*.

Answer (score 3):

A assinatura de um método é dada pelo número e tipos de argumentos do método, assim como por seu valor de retorno.