# Como adicionar métodos static em interface?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, interface, método, static

Tenho meu seguinte método:

```
 public static CloudStorageAccount GetAccount()
```

E na minha `Interface`:

```
  public interface IAzureStorangeService
  {
    CloudStorageAccount GetAccount()
  }
```

Porém o compilador acusa que não foi implementado o método na minha classe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não pode. Faz parte da especificação da linguagem. Métodos estáticos são métodos **pertencentes à classe** e não à instância da classe (ao objeto). Uma interface precisa ter seus métodos implementados na instância da classe. Podemos dizer que a implementação concreta na classe deve herdar da declaração abstrata existente na interface. E não é possível usar nada estático para herdar alguma coisa.

Métodos estáticos precisam ser totalmente determinados em tempo de compilação. A implementação concreta da interface pode ser determinada em tempo de execução. Não há compatibilidade entre essas funcionalidades.

Só para entender a diferença entre método estático e de instância:

- o método estático é como se fosse uma função normal, ele é chamado exatamente daquela forma como ele é declarado, essencialmente o compilador não dá nenhum tratamento especial a ele. A única coisa a mais que deve ser considerada é que no nome dele inclui o nome da classe (você nem sempre verá isto mas internamente está lá);
- o método de instância esconde o primeiro parâmetro. Você não vê ele mas sempre tem um parâmetro chamado `this` nele. Este parâmetro é a instância. Usando seu exemplo e considerando que sua classe fosse chamada `CloudStorage` seria algo assim:

  Você declara na classe:

  ```
    public CloudStorageAccount GetAccount()
  ```

  E ele compila para:

  ```
    public CloudStorageAccount GetAccount(CloudStorage this)
  ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/HiddenThis.cs).

O que você também não vê em uma declaração de método na interface mas está lá é que todo método na interface é público e virtual. Como todos são assim, não tem porque declará-lo. Nem faria sentido se não fosse assim. E se o método é virtual, ele deve possuir uma tabela virtual que será acessada dinamicamente (de acordo com o uso em tempo de execução). Esta tabela indica qual é o tipo concreto que está sendo implementado no uso corrente. Esta tabela está vinculada ao tipo concreto utilizado pelo `this`. Note que tipo concreto se refere ao tipo real que a sua classe foi instanciada. Com um método estático esta tabela não existe afinal o método não pertence à instância alguma.

A [assinatura de um método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) estático então é diferente de um método de instância. Não bate, apesar de ter o mesmo nome, ele não é o mesmo método. Por isto o erro parece indicar algo diferente do que realmente está acontecendo, por isto o compilador acha que você não declarou o método.

[Resposta no SO sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/259079/221800).

C# 8 que saiu em 2019 permite métodos estáticos em interfaces (se tudo correr bem). Mas ainda só fará sentido chamando direto pelo tipo e não pela instância. Pensando bem isto sempre foi possível, só não fazia muito sentido. Como em C# 8 muda a filosofia do que a interface pode fazer, começa fazer algum sentido. Quando sair podem perguntar mais sobre o funcionamento específico.

Em C# 10 já é possível mais flexibilidade ainda, pelo menos de forma experimental, no 11 ficará definitivo.

Answer (score 6):

Não é possível implementar um método da interface usando um método estático.

Interfaces existem para definir um contrato entre a classe e utilizadores de instâncias do objeto. Para isso acontecer, é permitido fazer um type-cast da instância do objeto para o tipo da interface:

```
var @interface = (IMinhaInterface)objeto;
@interface.MetodoDaInterface(); // agora sim temos acesso à interface a partir do objeto
```

Ou seja, tudo relacionado à interfaces fala sobre instâncias do objeto, utilizáveis através do type-cast acima.

Você pode entretanto, implementar como uma parte estática da classe, o padrão singleton, o que permite que você use a interface para algo estático (pelo menos algo que será servido de forma estática). Ou então usar um framework de injeção de dependências, que permite usar objetos em contextos estáticos, e servi-los aos seus dependentes.