# Quando incrementar a versão usando Semantic Versioning?

Tags: versionamento, semver

Ao usar Semantic Versioning definimos diferentes versões no formato X.Y.Z sendo X, Y, Z inteiros não negativos. Dessa forma, dada uma versão X.Y.Z:

- Incrementamos X se uma modificação incompatível com a versão atual for feita
- Incrementamos Y se uma nova funcionalidade compatível com a API atual é adicionada
- Incrementamos Z se uma correção de bug compatível com a API atual é realizada

No terceiro caso é muito fácil saber quando incrementar. Temos um bug, corrigimos ele sem quebrar a API e aí devemos incrementar.

Nos dois primeiros casos parece ser mais complicado. No segundo caso por exemplo, uma nova funcionalidade pode ser uma simples adição de um método em uma classe, quanto a criação de várias novas classes que juntas permitem satisfazer um dado requisito.

No primeiro caso também tem isso. Uma modificação pode afetar uma única linha de código ou vários arquivos.

Dessa forma, nesses dois primeiros casos, como sabemos a quantidade de modificação que realmente faz sentido incrementar a versão?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Não sabemos. No fundo, até que alguém me apresente um estudo confiável que mostre o contrário, isto é mais ou menos arbitrário.

Você deve estar se referindo ao conceito descrito no [*site* "oficial"](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/) sobre o assunto. Ali tem algumas regrinhas, mas é tudo muito genérico, como deve ser mesmo.

## Bug

Você definiu bem como proceder no terceiro caso. Mas lembre-se que uma correção de *bug* pode quebrar a API. Algumas pessoas talvez digam que se o *bug* era tão sério que quebra a API então é uma melhoria. Pode ser, mas eu não sei até onde vai esta discussão, e o quanto é relevante.

O que eu percebo é que muitos projetos onde a comunidade tem voz perde-se mais tempo discutindo qual versão deve incrementar do que melhorando código :P

## Maior X Menor

#### Herança

Não sei se é tão difícil identificar a diferença do primeiro e segundo casos. Criar uma classe nova normalmente não cria incompatibilidades. Criar um método novo normalmente não cria também. Embora possa criar problemas em alguns casos.

Quando você cria um método novo em uma classe que normalmente é herdada potencialmente cria incompatibilidades. Essa não é uma prática recomendada, então talvez conte como uma modificação que gere incompatibilidade e cairia no primeiro caso.

Não tenho experiência com o assunto e não gosto muito destes formalismos quando eles não resolvem problemas reais. Em muitos casos documentos formais não podem resolver nada. Dito isto, mesmo que o documento não especifique nada eu adotaria esta política de mudar a versão maior sempre que você introduza uma mudança potencialmente incompatível. A não ser que estivesse documentado que este método poderia ser criado no futuro e que ninguém poderia criar um método com mesmo nome/[assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

Se você está provendo uma API que pode ser herdada este perigo existe. Se não há a possibilidade de herança ou se sua aplicação não provê uma API pública que pode ser acessa programaticamente de forma direta, o risco não existe. Por isso as pessoas dizem para usar herança em último caso.

Você pode estar se perguntando porque a criação de um método pode ser compatível se não houver herança, e ser incompatível se houver. Herança é uma péssima ideia que deve ser usada com muito cuidado nos raros casos onde ela realmente é muito benéfica. Um dos motivos disto é justamente pelo fato que você não tem controle como sua classe será consumida. Se alguém criar um método chamado `B()` na classe filha, a classe mãe nunca mais poderá criar este método sem quebrar compatibilidade já que provavelmente este `B()` existente não faz o que se espera dele de acordo com o novo contrato na classe mãe.

Herança é tão complicada que alguns programadores preferem criar uma classe nova do que um método novo quando precisa melhorar uma classe existente. Assim a mudança que seria incompatível se torna compatível. Mas cria duas classes para manter e para as pessoas escolherem e usarem.

#### Implementação

Uma mudança na implementação, mesmo que mantenha a casca da API compatível, pode tornar necessária uma mudança de versão maior. Tecnicamente se você pode continuar usando a API da mesma forma mas o resultado pode ser diferente, você tem uma mudança incompatível. Embora, tecnicamente, você não deveria mudar resultados da API sem mudá-la oficialmente (documentar isso). Alguns dirão que a API foi modificada neste caso, discutível, mas pode ser.

Talvez o pior a ser feito seria tornar incompatível algo sem deixar claro que está incompatível.

Por isto eu acho mais difícil saber se você está no primeiro ou terceiro caso. Uma simples correção de *bug* pode inadvertidamente tornar a API incompatível, mesmo que não seja a intenção. Testes consistentes vão ajudar nisto. Mas quem testa consistentemente os testes consistentes?

#### Obsolescência

Acho que é bem óbvio que retirada de funcionalidades torna a mudança incompatível, certo?

## Conclusão

Ou seja, não é a quantidade de modificação que vai definir qual versão mudar e sim a qualidade dela. Uma única vírgula modificada pode trazer uma incompatibilidade e milhares de linhas novas podem apenas corrigir um *bug* ou fazer uma melhoria na implementação (mudar a complexidade de O(n) para O(log n), por exemplo) e tudo continuar funcionando igual.

Um dos motivos para a criação desta especificação é diminuir o número de mudanças incompatíveis e aumentar o planejamento. No mundo ideal a versão nunca deveria passar de `1.y.z`.

Fora estas observações e seguir o que o documento sobre versionamento semântico diz, acho que qualquer decisão é subjetiva, mesmo que tente usar critérios objetivos. O próprio documento fala em bom senso. Tem gente que tem, tem gente que não, e não sei se isto pode ser ensinado.

Pode ser o seu caso, mas na maioria dos casos reais os programadores não produzem APIs acessíveis e a versão semântica formalmente definida dificilmente trará grande vantagem. De fato, o primeiro item do documento exige que exista uma API para usar o termo formalmente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).