# Como definir a versão de um software?

Tags: versionamento, software

Gostaria de saber o que são e como funcionam os número das versões de softwares, como por exemplo `v1.1.2` o que significa ? Existe algum padrão ou recomendação para versões de aplicações web ?

Comment: +1, ja trabalhei em empresas que bolam loucura na contagem de versão, se existe um padrão eu não sei, depende muito do tempo que e liberado a versão, se ele coleta iterações (commits) como contagem ou apenas módulos. Na minha empresa enviamos versões com a data  e cada versão colocamos uma letra do alfabeto que consideramos como  versão do mês

Comment: Tem uma distro bem famosa de Linux que quando lança a versão 15.10, está te dizendo "Versão ano 2015, mês 10"; tem sistema operacional que pula a versão 9; tem outros que quando chega no 10 começam a usar algarismos romanos. E tem o google que põe beta em tudo e larga assim por anos e anos (aí quando sai do beta mexe em tudo que funcionava direito, e todo mundo tem que aprender a usar a aplicação de novo, mas aí ja saí do tópico).

Comment: @Bacco +1, Ótimo seu cometário e adendo ao "método" do google rs, Obrigado.

Comment: O que o Bacco disse é o que eu coloquei na minha resposta, qualquer tentativa de adivinhar o que estes número são, não dá certo. Tem que "perguntar" para quem bolou estes números, só ele sabe qual o critério que usou. Mas alguém achou que a resposta merecia um negativo por não tentar adivinhar. Ou talvez por não repetir o que eu já havia respondido antes.

Comment: @bigown achei sua resposta ótima, além de esclarecer me informou um link onde entendi melhor como funciona, infelizmente nem todos concordam!

Comment: @devgaspa eu até entendo que não estejam votando muito porque não detalhei muito, afinal eu já havia feito em outra resposta, não tinha porque eu repetir aqui o que está escrito lá. Eu já expliquei o SemVer com bastante detalhes (seria até legal as pessoas votarem mais lá do que aqui mesmo, aquela resposta está mais legal que esta pincelada que dei aqui). Mas negativar algo que não tem nada errado é sacanagem.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber o que são e como funcionam os número das versões de softwares, como por exemplo `v1.1.2` o que significa?

Segundo o [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/):

- O primeiro número indica que o sistema tem mudanças que o torna incompatível com versões anteriores;
- O segundo número indica que o sistema tem mudanças compatíveis com versões anteriores, dentro do primeiro número;
- O terceiro número indica que o sistema tem mudanças menores, como correções de bugs e funcionalidades que não prejudicam a compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Opcionalmente, define-se um quarto número, chamado de release. Indica o número atual do *build* daquele código, dentro de um escopo de modificações.

> Existe algum padrão ou recomendação para versões de aplicações web?

O versionamento semântico pode ser usado. Alguns outros sistemas utilizam um número de versionamento formado pela data do lançamento. Isto é adotado quando as modificações são frequentes (para não dizer diárias) e que não vale a pena levar em consideração uma abordagem semântica.

Exemplos:

- `Ano.Mes.Dia.Build`;
- `Ano.Mes.Dia.Estado`. Estado pode ser `Alpha`, `Beta`, `dev`, `stable`, etc.;
- `Ano.Mes.Major.Minor.Fix` (também pode ter o estado ou o release no final);

Cada equipe acaba inventando o seu formato. Estes são alguns que já vi e usei.

Comment: Não sei se isso é ou não padronizado pelo versionamento semântico, mas seria uma boa ideia que versões onde só o terceiro número muda fossem compatíveis "pra trás" (*backward compatibility*) e "pra frente" (*forward compatibility*) - de modo que um arquivo salvo no `1.2.3` por exemplo possa ser aberto com sucesso no `1.2.0` (i.e. se essa compatibilidade pra frente não puder ser satisfeita, o ideal é mudar o segundo número, ainda que a mudança seja pequena). Já no segundo número basta ser compatível pra trás (ex.: o que se salva no `1.2` se abre no `1.3`, mas não necessariamente o contrário).

Comment: @mgibsonbr É o que o versionamento sugere, aliás, mas já tive oportunidade de conhecer sistemas em que arquivos salvos, por exemplo, numa versão `1.2.3` não abrem na `1.2.0`. Um caso clássico era o Guitar Pro versões 4 e 5.

Answer (score 11):

Não existe um padrão. Cada projeto adota o que melhor lhe convier, então a explicação do que cada número (se é que números são usados) significam deve ser fornecida pelo próprio projeto.

O que existe de recomendação é o versionamento semântico. Mesmo estabelecendo algumas regras, elas são subjetivas. Isto já foi [respondido em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51820/101) (não vou repetir aqui o que já foi respondido antes).

E há uma [pergunta no Software Engineering com alguns padrões possíveis para se adotar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3199/389). Tem "respostas" minhas lá e vários outros exemplos como dá para usar a criatividade e não se pode confiar na intuição para determinar o que os números representam.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Geralmente cada empresa define a sua metodologia de versionamento. 
Um padrão bastante comum utilizado no mercado é o seguinte: 
VERSÃO. RELEASE. REVISÃO

VERSÃO: Acrescenta-se um numero a VERSÃO se o projeto for uma evolução.

RELEASE: Acrescenta-se um numero a RELEASE se o projeto for uma melhoria (ex: exclusão ou inclusão de novas funcionalidades).

REVISÃO: Acrescenta-se um numero a REVISÃO se o projeto for uma correção de funcionalidades já existentes.