# Para que serve cada número (que são separados por ponto-final) nos versionamentos?

Tags: versionamento, biblioteca

Geralmente, em bibliotecas (falo de qualquer linguagem de programação), temos a versão atual da biblioteca. Não falo de algo como `Symfony 2` ou `jQuery 2` (que são nomes usados geralmente para apresentar a biblioteca), mas falo daquelas versões que tem um três números separados por pontos.

Por exemplo:

```
 Windows 6.1.12 (Windows 8, eu acho)
 jQuery 1.11.1 ou 1.10.12
 Laravel 4.2.6 (Todo mundo fala apenas Laravel 4)
```

Eu gostaria de entender o que cada ponto desse significa, pois também trabalho com bibliotecas e gostaria de poder entender como trabalhar melhor com o versionamento das mesmas.

## Perguntas de exemplo

- Qual seria, teoricamente, a diferença entre jQuery 1.10.12 e jQuery 1.11.0?
- Qual seria, teoricamente, a diferença entre jQuery 1.10.0 e jQuery 1.10.5?
- Qual seria, teoricamente, a diferença entre jQuery 1.11.23 e jQuery 2.0.0?

Comment: O Cigano também me mostrou que já tinha aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101896/como-definir-a-vers%C3%A3o-de-um-software/101899#101899

Comment: Nesses casos fica mais legal quando cada um vota numa duplicata diferente, pois as duas (ou mais) aparecem na caixa amarela.