# O que poderia justificar o pulo de um número em um sistema de versionamento?

Tags: versionamento

Percebi que o tão sonhado PHP 6 foi cancelado. Então, misteriosamente, da versão 5 pularam diretamente para a versão 7.

Me surgiu então uma dúvida quanto ao desenvolvimento de bibliotecas e seus respectivos números de versionamento:

- Existe alguma justificativa plausível que poderia ocasionar esse pulo de número de versionamento quanto ao desenvolvimento de uma biblioteca? Por exemplo, se eu tenho uma biblioteca com as versões `1.0`, `1.1` e `2.0`, existiria algum fator que implicasse na numeração sendo avançada para `4.0`?
- Com base no exemplo do PHP 7, em um sistema de versionamento, o que importa é os números crescerem em sequência, ou eles só precisam simplesmente crescer (independentemente da sequência "1, 2, 3") para demonstrar a mudança da versão?

**Nota**: *Notar que utilizei o PHP simplesmente como exemplo. O intuito da pergunta não é saber o que aconteceu com o versionamento do PHP, mas foi apenas um exemplo para tentar entender o que leva uma biblioteca/aplicativo a pular os números da versão.*

Comment: Justificativa tem pra praticamente qualquer coisa. No caso do PHP não foi misteriosamente, a versão 6 já tinha sido produzida e já tinham até livros sobre ela (com suporte a unicode e outras coisas) então pelo fato de terem feito esse tipo de "divulgação" acharam melhor pular essa versão.

Comment: É marketing... Zuera... Mas olha o 7 ai outra vez....Sério...

Comment: O que dizer então do windows? 95, 98, 2000, ME, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10

Comment: Se bem que, comi bola, esses são apenas os nomes dados às realese, de qualquer forma do windows 8.1 (NT 6.3) pulou para o windows 10 (NT 10.0)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio internamente, o Windows tem uma versão interna :p (agora que vi que você se retratou)

Comment: PHP 5.3 é o PHP 6, mas como não conseguiram finalizar o suporte completo ao Unicode (limitação e problemas), resolveram lançar como PHP 5.3. Pode verificar que a mudança do PHP 5.2 para o PHP 5.3 é gigantesca

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio isso são nomes do produto e não versão, esses produtos possuem versão 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.alguma coisa que não lembro, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1 (sim, o 7 é versão 6 :) ), 6.2, 6.3 e 6.4. Agora depois de alguma atualizações o W10 passou para versão 10. Eu falo dessa maluquice da MS na minha resposta. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history

Comment: Teve software lançado na versão 3.x , o cara vê e acha que a bagaça é estável ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade, sim e não. Plausível precisaria de uma definição. O fato é que as mudanças de número de versão são sempre feitas por humanos e quase arbitrárias.

## Semantic Versioning

Quando se faz [SemVer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/101) está adotando um critério claro e tenta-se ser menos arbitrário, busca-se ser mais objetivo quando mudar o número, mas ainda assim será feito por um ser humano que tem um grau de subjetividade. Mesmo que faça o versionamento semântico, **nada impede de não segui-lo por alguma razão**. Quando não faz, o critério apenas é um pouco diferente, provavelmente mais flexível.

Uma razão é algum imprevisto no processo, por exemplo o abandono de toda uma especificação. Já ocorreu com PHP, JS e diversas tecnologias.

## Organização

Em tese os números nem precisam ser em sequência, ainda que seria uma loucura não fazer assim.

Tem gente que sequer usam números para versões, ou não usam essa organização em níveis. [Há modelo de tudo quanto é jeito](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/3199/389). Claro que esse da pergunta é o mais adotado.

Tem produto que não tem critério claro, só vai subindo números. Depois que o Linux começou fazer isso vários produtos fizeram o mesmo.

## Marketing

Tem um monte de tecnologia que pulou números, muitas vezes por marketing. Isso é plausível? A Microsoft faz muito isso. Procure por Entity Framework 2 ou 3. Muitas vezes isso ocorre para "sincronizar" com outros produtos. Mas o mais comum é para passar a ideia que o produto é muito melhor. A Microsoft sempre foi péssima para versionar produtos. Como MVP nem devia dizer isso, mas eles disseram que sou independente para falar o que penso, senão eu nem queria. Eles que melhorem isso. [Vide versão do Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history).

Teve época que todos produtos de tecnologia queriam ser versão 5. Estrambolicamente 5 queria dizer orientado a objeto e todo mundo queria pegar esse bonde, mesmo que não fosse OOP. Foi uma época louca :) Totalmente arbitrário.

## Justificativa

No caso do PHP foi por lambança, o plausível aí foi consertar o problema que eles causaram dando nome pra uma versão que eles não sabiam do que se tratava ainda, que não sabiam se seria aquilo mesmo. Os desenvolvedores do PHP (os que fazem a implementação da linguagem) sempre foram ingênuos (o que nada tem a ver com a capacidade técnica deles, que no geral eu não discuto), todo mundo antenado sabe disso.

Muita coisa foi divulgada como *feature* do 6 e que não teria mais. A solução foi pular para o 7. Então o 7 tem menos coisas que 6, ainda que o 6 nunca tenha sido lançado oficialmente.

## Conclusão

Cada um faz como quiser, mas se quer ter algum significado adote um critério.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

A grande maioria dos projetos adotam [este padrão de versionamento](http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/), que basicamente consiste em (retirado do próprio site):

Dado um número de versão MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, incremente a:

1. versão Maior(MAJOR): quando fizer mudanças incompatíveis na API,
2. versão Menor(MINOR): quando adicionar funcionalidades mantendo compatibilidade, e
3. versão de Correção(PATCH): quando corrigir falhas mantendo compatibilidade.

Rótulos adicionais para pré-lançamento(pre-release) e metadados de construção(build) estão disponíveis como extensão ao formato MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.

Você pode ler sobre os motivos pelo qual o PHP 5.x pulou para 7 [aqui](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php6) e [aqui](https://ma.ttias.be/php6-missing-version-number/) mas resumidamente é:

### Marketing

Houve tentativas de lançar o PHP 6 em 2005, mas não deu certo. Com o tempo passando, o nome "PHP 6" foi ganhando uma má fama pela demora no lançamento.

Apesar disso, PHP 6 realmente já existia e era algo totalmente diferente. Nunca atingiu uma disponibilidade geral, mas era um projeto amplamente publicado e conhecido, conduzido por php.net.

Pular versões não é uma exclusividade do PHP, também já ocorreu em outros projetos como: MariaDB, Netscape Communicator, Symantec, IP (o próprio Internet Protocol), etc.

Comment: Caramba, essa do ip eu nunca parei pra notar que ipv4 pulou pra ipv6 até ler sua resposta kkkk

Comment: Detalhe curioso.... o IPv5 realmente existiu, IPv5 foi utilizado para definir um protocolo de *real-time streaming* que era experimental. Para evitar confusões, foi decidido não usar IPv5 e nomear o novo protocolo IP como IPv6. ([Fonte](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-no-iPv5-after-iPv4/answer/Virendra-Giri-1))