# Qual a diferença entre as versões 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 do Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Eu pensava que o Python só atualizava as versões 2.7 para manter compatibilidade mas a 3.x abandonasse versões anteriores. Porém ele insiste em atualizar as versões 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 constantemente. O que essas diversas versões 3.x.x tem de diferente?

O Python não poderia apenas seguir com a versão 2.7 e 3.7 e abandonar a 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 ?

Comment: Primeiro, você precisa entender como funciona o [esquema de versionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51817/quando-incrementar-a-vers%C3%A3o-usando-semantic-versioning).

Comment: É preciso entender que cada numerozinho aí faz diferença. Recomendo ler [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101899/4995) sobre como os softwares são versionados.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quando incrementar a versão usando Semantic Versioning?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51817/quando-incrementar-a-vers%c3%a3o-usando-semantic-versioning)

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/releases

Comment: CHANGELOG: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html o que há de novo a partir 3.0: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Não é questão de abandonar, o link do wallace é perfeito para explicar, o 3.4 até o 3.6 recebem correções de segurança, pois existem sistemas que ainda os usam, não quer dizer que vão receber funcionalidades que mudem essas versões, só correções mesmo com compatibilidade. Ou seja internamente vai ser 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3 em diante. Isto porque existem sistemas que foram escritos nestas versões especificas (de range especifico como `3.4.x`), ai podem haver bugs ou problemas de segurança, isso eles continuam a dar suporte, mas em alguns anos provavelmente abandonem...

Comment: ...só que eles não podem fazer isso do nada, pois se não sistemas que já usam os ranges específicos podem ficar inseguros ou quebrarem por bugs, agora se um software escrito em 3.4 fosse colocado no 3.7 para rodar talvez ele não funcionasse, pois geralmente quando o range é da segunda "casa" (`3.x`) podem não manter a compatibilidade.

Comment: Só pra constar a 2.7 não é mantida por "compatibilidade", mas sim pq muitos sistemas ainda o usam, até mesmo sistemas operacionais vem com python2.7 nativamente, e muitos softwares bons ainda não puderam ser migrados, pois demanda tempo, python3 é muito diferente do 2 (falo não só de algumas sintaxes, mas de libs internas também) para poder migrar em um bom tempo.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, acabei de me atualizar para Python 3.7 e PySide2 com Qt5.

Comment: Reverti sua edição, @thegrapevine. Votei para a reabertura dessa pergunta, acho que é cabível assim como https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178464/o-que-poderia-justificar-o-pulo-de-um-n%C3%BAmero-em-um-sistema-de-versionamento :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ideia que você tinha anteriormente está certa - a única versão realmente antiga que ainda é atualizada é a 2.7.

As outras versões são atualizadas, mas com atualizações de bugs e de segurança - sem funcionalidades novas.

Funcionalidades novas sempre entram apenas na versão com um "minor number" novo (o "7" no "3.7", por exemplo). Ha algumas APIs da biblioteca padrão que que são chamadas de "provisional" - essas e apenas essas, podem mudar e ter diferenças entre a versão 3.7.0 e 3.7.1 (por exemplo) - veja a [PEP 411](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0411/)

Acontece que muitos sistemas são feitos e dependem de versões específicas do Python - a linguagem tenta não gerar nenhuma quebra, mas até mesmo verificar se nada deu errado com a versão nova pode ser custoso num sistema grande, muito crítico.

Além de sistemas que dependem de versões específicas, outras empresas preferem depender do Python que acompanha o sistema operacional, em vez de colocar um Python personalizado - e algumas distribuições para servidor podem ter defasagem de alguns anos em seus pacotes. (E, fora que atualizar a distribuição inteira de um servidor onde você pode ter vários sistemas rodando é ainda mais crítico que atualizar só o Python) O Redhat enterprise Linux, por exemplo, tem manutenção garantida por 10 anos (https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata )

Então, após o lançamento de cada versão do Python, há um período em que ela é considerada "mantida", e vai receber correções de bugs e  atualizações de segurança. Depois disso, um outro período de tempo em que novos bugs descobertos não são arrumados, somente atualizações de segurança. Até atingir o "fim da linha" - nesse ponto a versão é considerada descontinuada e não vai receber nenhuma atualização oficial.

Para o Python esses períodos são: a última e a penúltima versão são ativamente mantidas para receberem correções de bugs (no caso de hoje, agosto de 2018, são a 3.7 e a 3.6). As duas versões anteriores recebem correções de segurança - e somente de segurança - (essas são a 3.5 e 3.4). E a 2.7 recebe correções de bugs e documentação até 1/1/2020 - quando então não será mais mantida.

Uma nova versão da linguagem é lançada a cada um ano e meio mais ou menos, então, **na média, um sistema feito com o Python mais novo vai poder contar com correções de bugs por 3 anos, e correções de segurança por 6 anos.**

Note que empresas privadas que tem contrato de manutenção de segurança para produtos que incluem as versões antigas do Python podem continuar colocando atualizações de segurança em versões mais antigas - por exemplo, a Redhat deve continuar, por conta própria, corrigindo vulnerabilidades no Python 2.7 após o final da linha dele, em 2020 - até o final da manutenção do último RedHat Enterprise Linux que incluiu o Python 2.7. Essas atualizações por empresas privadas podem ser compartilhadas publicamente, e etc... mas não vão mais gerar releases oficiais dessas versões antigas de Python. Quem precisar das mesmas vai ter que buscar na internet os patches e aplicar por conta (ou ter um contrato com a mantenedora pra fazer isso).