# Como fazer versionamento semântico?

Tags: versionamento, semver

estou trabalhando com um software em Visual Basic, que já existe a algum tempo, porém não usa versionamento semântico padronizado, li alguns artigos como o semver.org e tive duas dúvidas:

1 - O que realmente o artigo quer dizer com "API pública?", pois o software é fechado, e embora tenha lido a respeito das APIs, não consegui identificar no software que trabalho essa tal "API pública".

2 - Entendi como funcionam o MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, mas como devo organizar o software no GitHub pra se adequar a isso, pra que fique organizado o trabalho?

Li bastante coisa sobre o assunto, mas algumas dúvidas ainda pairam no ar, se puderem ajudar, agradeço. Abrass!

Comment: Acho que isto responde: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178464/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/101

Comment: Depende, você pretende dar suporte e manutenção em versões anteriores ou apenas da versão atual?

Comment: Maniero, acabei recaindo nas mesmas questões acima... o que seria minha API pública é a principal dúvida.

Comment: Pretendo apenas manter a versão atual e seguir fazendo as alterações necessárias