# Quando e por que usar o atributo Obsolete?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, atributos

Pelo menos nos projetos os quais trabalhei, não vejo sentido em usar o atributo [`Obsolete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) em métodos que não são mais utilizados. O que faço, e vejo pessoas fazendo é remover ou comentar códigos que não são mais utilizados/obsoletos.

Quando devo e por que utilizar o atributo Obsolete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em coisas simples, internas (ninguém fora da sua equipe ou você mesmo vai usar **seu código**) não precisa usar mesmo. Você tem controle total sobre o uso e se aquilo foi usado, você consegue rapidamente com ajuda do IDE, e quem sabe algum *plugin*, mudar tudo que usa o que foi [deprecado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178138/101).

Em códigos que são usados extensivamente e/ou é disponibilizado para terceiros esse tipo de marcação é fundamental. Você não pode remover algo que pode estar sendo usado por terceiros. Tem que mostrar que o seu uso não é o ideal, fazer o compilador indicar isso para ele. Pode ser que em versões futuras até possa remover, mas o normal é até nunca remover, a não ser que lance um produto todo reformulado.

Esse atributo é uma documentação semântica para indicar que aquele código não deve ser usado em projetos futuros e se possível deve mudar para outra coisa mais moderna onde já foi usado.

É comum usar uma mensagem curta indicando o que usar no lugar.

É possível indicar se vai gerar um *warning* ou erro de compilação. O ideal é começar com um *warning* e documentar quando virará erro. É bom lançar pelo menos uma versão do software dando erro de obsolescência antes de remover o código. Quando remover o erro será outro e não dará nenhuma indicação que aquilo se tornou obsoleto. Provavelmente adotando [SemVer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/101).

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).