# Como fazer o Versionamento Semântico (SemVer) com o GIT?

Tags: git, commit, release, semver

Uma dúvida que sempre tive e me dá muita dor de cabeça, é sobre como eu devo fazer o Versionamento Semântico com o GIT.

Eu deveria levar em consideração o **commit**, um **"release"** do projeto, ou outra coisa?

## Release

Exemplo de um histórico de *commit's* com o tipo de alteração levando em consideração que o número de versão seja definida num ***release***.

#### v2.1.4 - Release 04

(O release teve ***1 major***, ***1 minor*** e ***4 patches***)

- Patch
- Major
- Patch
- Patch
- Minor
- Patch

#### v1.3.4 - Release 03

(O release teve ***2 minors*** e ***4 patches***)

- Patch
- Patch
- Minor
- Patch
- Patch
- Patch
- Minor

#### v1.1.5 - Release 02

(O release teve ***1 minor*** e ***5 patches***)

- Patch
- Patch
- Minor
- Patch
- Patch
- Patch

#### v1.0.3 - Release 01

(O release teve ***3 patches***)

- Patch
- Patch
- Patch

## Commit

Exemplo de um histórico de *commit's* com o tipo de alteração levando em consideração que o número de versão seja definida assim que um ***commit seja feito***.

#### v2.0.1 - Release 04

- Patch (**2.0.1**)
- Major (**2.0.0**)
- Patch (**1.4.2**)
- Patch (**1.4.1**)
- Minor (**1.4.0**)
- Patch (**1.3.2**)

#### v1.3.1 - Release 03

- Patch (**1.3.1**)
- Minor (**1.3.0**)
- Patch (**1.2.3**)
- Patch (**1.2.2**)
- Patch (**1.2.1**)
- Minor (**1.2.0**)

#### v1.1.2 - Release 02

- Patch (**1.1.2**)
- Patch (**1.1.1**)
- Minor (**1.1.0**)
- Patch (**1.0.6**)
- Patch (**1.0.5**)
- Patch (**1.0.4**)

#### v1.0.3 - Release 01

- Patch (**1.0.3**)
- Patch (**1.0.2**)
- Patch (**1.0.1**)

Da pra ver que tiveram versões diferentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a especificação da pra dizer qual seria a maneira de se fazer? (Mesmo que não seja essas), ou é algo em que a equipe decide e não tem nada que afirme?

Comment: Você precisa saber qual tipo de lançamento (portanto, `release`) está fazendo para saber em que ponto do `M.m.i` você vai incrementar. Não faz sentido fechar uma versão sem fechar. E, dependendo do que entrou, você precisa subir um ou outro número

Comment: Mas a maneira como estou fazendo no exemplo de `release` está correta?

Comment: Eu diria que não. Cada versão para mim seria uma `release` diferente. Não juntaria diversas versões em um lançamento. Só faz sentido você subir a versão quando há lançamento, então dizer que uma `release` consiste de 6 versões eu vejo como uma ofensa ao versionamento semântico pior do que xingar a mãe. Você pode ter diversos tipos de correção em um lançamento, mas isso só implicaria subir um dos números do `M.m.i` e zerar os números menos significativos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Acredito que entendi, me sinto mais tranquilo agora. Apenas pra confirmar, vamos dizer que o app se encontra na versão `1.4.3` e nela eu fiz várias correções (patch) e mudanças incompatíveis na API (major), então o `release` seria versão `2.0.0`?

Comment: isso mesmo. Mais tarde verifico se já tem uma resposta adequada e, não havendo, escrevo uma

Comment: Sim, a própria especificação define: "Uma vez que um pacote versionado foi lançado(released), o conteúdo desta versão NÃO DEVE ser modificado. Qualquer modificação DEVE ser lançado como uma nova versão" ou seja do MAJOR `1.x.x` só poderia seguir pra o MAJOR `2.x.x`. https://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/#spec-item-3

Comment: E ao meu ver, você não define a versão com base no commit. Criar, por exemplo, uma alteração da versão 1.x para 2.0 seria, provavelmente, uma alteração grande demais para apenas um commit apenas. O ideal é commitar sob necessidade e as versões definirem com as tags.

Comment: @ViníciusLima, creio que seja duplicata dessa aqui, mas não tenho certeza: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Essa ajuda, mas não é exatamente a dúvida da pergunta que era realmente sobre o uso do GIT, o que eu deveria levar em consideração para definir a versão que no caso dei o exemplo de `release` e `commits` que ambos estavam incorretos. Mas você já me tirou a dúvida nos comentários no 3° comentário da pergunta pra ser mais exato. _"Eu diria que não. Cada versão para mim seria uma release diferente, etc..."_

Answer (score 3):

tudo certo?

Estarei fazendo um pequeno resumo com base em alguns artigos e conteúdos sobre "Semantic Version".

0.0.***1*** 
 **Patch**: 

 - Utilizado para informar "hot-fixes" e eles não alteram a funcionalidade do código, porém resolvem "bugs".


 *Observação*: É incrementado sempre por uma unidade e não possuí limites em sua aplicação. 

 Exemplo: 0.1.***30***

0.***1***.0

***Minor***:

 - Utilizado para representar novas funcionalidades(features) no projeto.

*Observação*: Quando incrementado reseta todas as unidades de "patch" anteriores ou seja resultando em uma nova funcionalidade sem "bugs" até o momento. 
 Também incrementa por uma unidade. 

 Exemplo: 0.***0***.15 --> 0.***1***.0

***1***.0.0

***Major***:

 - Representa uma versão incompatível ou alguma alteração drástica no projeto.


*Observação*: Incrementa-se por uma unidade e quando atualizado, reseta-se versões de "minor" e "patch". 

 
Exemplo: Uma biblioteca utiliza estancias para sua utilização e na sua próxima versão utiliza exportação nomeada para utilizar suas funcionalidades. Sendo assim incompatível a forma anterior de sua utilização. ***0***.5.10 --> ***1***.0.0

**Bibliografia**:

[A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)
[A quick intro to Semantic Versioning: what it is, and why we use it](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/semantic-versioning-1fd6f57749f7)
[What is Semantic Versioning?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdzJuQdjKOE)

Espero tê-lo ajudado!