# Uso de frameworks exige atualizações?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, framework, owl-carousel

Olá

Estou utilizando alguns frames como o Bootstrap, jQuery e Owl Carousel e gostaria de saber se é preciso atualizar meu código sempre que estes frameworks atualizarem suas versões.

É seguro, no sentido de quebrar meu código, utilizar esses frameworks?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas se você atualizar as versões que for utilizar na aplicação.

Quando você instala esses frameworks como dependência na sua aplicação você define qual é a versão exata que deseja utilizar. Novas versões dos frameworks não irão interferir na sua aplicação, a menos que você manualmente os atualiza. Essa independência entre as versões fica muito mais evidente quando você utiliza um gerenciador de dependências e os frameworks utilizam [versionamento semântico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51817/5878).

Você só precisará alterar o código da sua aplicação quando você optar por atualizar as dependências e as alterações que foram feitas entre a versão atual e a nova são incompatíveis. Muitas alterações feitas nos frameworks são retro compatíveis e podem ser atualizados sem medo.

Cabe a você primeiro decidir se a atualização das dependências é necessária e, se for, analisar o que foi alterado nessas versões e verificar se algo tornou-se incompatível com a sua aplicação. Verificar o arquivo CHANGELOG costuma facilitar isso, dado que geralmente traz um resumo de todas as alterações feitas em cada versão.

Comment: Interessante Anderson. Não sabia que eu poderia escolher a versão de acordo com a dependência que tenho e baixá-la. 

Mas, e no caso de usar um CDN? Como estou usando no jQuery.

Comment: @Psycintra E na URL do CDN que está utilizando não consta a versão?

Comment: Sim, consta a versão. Mas, na próxima atualização da mesma, sendo CDN, ele atualizará sozinho se meu site estiver na Web, ou eu preciso ir lá, na unha e alterar?

Comment: @Psycintra Irá sempre requisitar do CDN a versão que você informou. Só irá alterar se você manualmente alterar a URL.