# Switch case grande em C

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, switch

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para a faculdade e gostaria de saber qual a melhor opção, no sentido de otimização do código, de melhora mesmo.

Tenho um `switch` case para Menu, onde tenho 88 cases.

Tenho uma tela chamada "Ajuda", nessa tela, o usuário poderá escolher entre 88 telas.

Exemplo abaixo:

Para acessar a tela "Ajuda", ele deve digitar "ajuda"

Vai acessar essa tela `telaAjuda ();` com varias opções dentro dela.
Tais opções estão entre 1 e 88. Exemplo abaixo:

```
printf("\n\t Op1 ...................................1\n");
printf("\n\t Op2....................................2\n");
printf("\n\t Op3....................................3\n");
printf("\n\t Op4....................................4\n");
printf("\n\t Op5...................................5\n\n");
...
printf("\n\t Op88...................................88\n\n");
```

E de acordo com o que é escolhido, o usuário é levado para outra tela de numero determinado (Como se fosse um esquema de paginação de livros).

Se ele escolher e digitar o numero 3, ele será levado a tela Op3.

A tela que uso o `switch case` é a `subMenu_Ajuda ()` ,que chamo ela em baixo da ajuda(fiz duas funções distintas para isso, pois se eu quiser chamar o submenu ajuda em outro lugar do código, eu não vou precisar necessariamente chamar a tela ajuda junto), apenas para receber o valor digitado pelo usuário e a partir dele, escolher a opção no `switch case`.

Exemplo abaixo do subMenu_ajuda:

```
printf("\nnomePrograma : loginUsuario -> "); //usarlogin
scanf("%i", &opAjuda);

    switch (opAjuda) { //88 Cases

    case 1:
    system("clear");
    telaAjuda1 ();
    __fpurge(stdin);
    break;

    case 2:
    system("clear");
    telaAjuda2 ();
    __fpurge(stdin);
    break; 

    ...

    case 88:
    system("clear");
    telaAjuda88 ();
    __fpurge(stdin);
    break; 
}
```

Eu posso deixar o `switch case` desse tamanho mesmo ou é melhor eu criar um vetor para todos os `cases` e chamá-lo quando necessário?

Comment: É possível, teria que criar um vetor com com ponteiros para função. É uma recursos mais avançado que você não deve ter aprendido ainda. Quer que eu coloque uma resposta?

Comment: É, estamos agora na matéria de salvar em arquivo.txt. Não chegamos a esse ponto ainda. Se você puder me mostrar o caminho, eu agradeço. Apenas onde procurar e o que procurar já me ajuda muito.

Comment: O que faz o fpurge?

Comment: O __fpurge(stdin); é usado no linux, é a mesma coisa do fflush(stdin); do windows ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou entrar em outros pontos, só vou fazer o que é pedido.

Cria-se um *array* com ponteiro para funções. Todas as funções precisam existir e estar acessível pelo código para que pegue seus endereços.

Para acessar a função, primeiro pegamos o endereço correspondente de acordo com a opção digitada. A sintaxe para chamar uma função pelo seu endereço é achar o ponteiro seguido da passagem dos parâmetros. No caso de não ter parâmetros, basta colocar o `()`.

Lembrando que todas as funções precisam ser compatíveis. Ter a mesma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) (mesmo retorno e mesmos parâmetros).

```
printf("\nnomePrograma : loginUsuario -> "); //usarlogin
scanf("%i", &opAjuda);
//seria bom validar se está entre 1 e 88
void (*opcoes[])() = {&telaAjuda1, &telaAjuda2, ..., &telaAjuda88}; //assinatura
system("clear");
(*opcoes[opAjuda - 1])();
__fpurge(stdin);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jPQ9Mk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/omnehgwp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SwitchAlternative.c).

Obviamente ali na reticências precisa colocar o nome de todas as funções usando o operador `&` pegando seu endereço de cada função, que obviamente precisa existir.

Comment: Ah legal. Vou tentar fazer aqui. Obrigada. ;)