# Quantos "case" são possíveis em um "switch"?

Tags: vb.net, característica-linguagem, switch

```
Case 1
Informação.Text = "Olá Mundo!"

Case 2
Informação.Text = "Tudo bem com você?"

Case 3
Informação.Text = "Que horas são?"
```

Percebe-se que adicionei 3 (três) cases. Agora uma pergunta; tem limite o números de cases? Vamos ao exemplos:

```
Case 276384943
Informação.Text = "..."

Case 276384944
Informação.Text = "..."

Case 276384945
Informação.Text = "..."
```

Comment: Qual linguagem?

Comment: Visual Basic - NET

Comment: E o que exatamente quer saber?

Comment: Tem limite a quantidade de "cases" no projeto?

Comment: Não sei se há limite de case, pode usar quantos quiser. É claro que se tiver muitos é sinal de que precisa refatorar o código.

Comment: A minha preocupação é de repente atingir o limite o números de "cases". Pois não sei de muita coisa em programação e a forma mais simples que eu aprendi é o exemplo acima.

Comment: Sugiro que você comece [por aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) então, para conseguir entender melhor o funcionamento do `case`.

Comment: Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176676/27190) vai ajudar também no entendimento do case.

Comment: O limite imposto pela linguagem é arbitrariamente grande, que corresponde ao máximo de um número inteiro de 32 bits. Sendo que não faz sentido, porque o máximo de linhas em arquivo é 65.535 linhas. Mas ninguém passa isso, afinal.

Comment: @MarcosMeireles A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 10):

Quantos anos você acha que levará para escrever quase 300 milhões de `cases`? Já percebeu a impraticabilidade disso? Mesmo que sejam só alguns milhares, cabe no arquivo do código fonte que o compilador é capaz de processar?

A não ser que tenha um padrão que permite colocar isso em um laço, o que já elimina o `case`.

Como o gato comentou, se tiver muitos, e por muitos entenda algumas dezenas ou no máximo centenas, está fazendo algo errado. O compilador pode saber lidar, e lida com milhares, mas não faz sentido fazer isso. Muito provavelmente esse código fica melhor de forma computada, usando um laço ou *array* (tem algumas perguntas que falam disso em outras linguagens [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97604/101) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211841/101)).

Não se preocupe com isso, o `case` não foi criado para lidar com essa situação hipotética, ele se torna inútil antes do compilador chiar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).