# Como funciona o método equals()?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, equals

Em um exercício de um livro mostra um exemplo de sobrecarga do método `equals`, eu até entendi o conceito de que ele compara a referência entre dois objetos, porém no método: `public boolean equals(Object obj)` as coisas começaram a ficar meio confusas.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- O que significa esse retorno do método `equals`: `return (getConta() == ((ExemploContaEquals) obj).getConta());`
- Por que o `if` do método principal compara somente os dois últimos atributos dos objetos instanciados? Ou seja, só compara os números 20 e 21 dos objetos `obj1` e `obj2` respectivamente e os números 50 e 50 dos objetos `obj3` e `obj4`. Qual a diferença então de ter dois atributos?

  package modulo04.SobrecargaEquals;

  ```
   public class ExemploContaEquals {

       private int conta = 0;

       public ExemploContaEquals(int agencia, int conta){
           this.conta = conta;

       }

       public ExemploContaEquals(){
           this(0,0);
       }



       public int getConta(){
           return conta;
       }


       public boolean equals(Object obj){

           if(obj != null && obj instanceof ExemploContaEquals){

               return (getConta() == ((ExemploContaEquals) obj).getConta());

           }  else {
               return false;

           }

       }

   }
  ```

---

```
package modulo04.SobrecargaEquals;

public class ExemploContaEqualsPrincipal {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ExemploContaEquals obj1 = new ExemploContaEquals(10,20);
        ExemploContaEquals obj2 = new ExemploContaEquals(10,21);
        
        if(obj1.equals(obj2)){
            System.out.println("Contas iguais");
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Conta diferentes");
        }
        
        ExemploContaEquals obj3 = new ExemploContaEquals(10, 50);
        ExemploContaEquals obj4 = new ExemploContaEquals(20,50);
        
        if(obj3.equals(obj4)){
            System.out.println("Contas iguais");
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Contas difentes");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bom, vamos lá.

Sobre o seguinte ponto:

> O que siginifica esse retorno do método equals: return (getConta() == ((ExemploContaEquals) obj).getConta());

Ele está verificando se a instância corrente da classe `ExemploContaEquals` possui (pegando o atributo `conta` como parâmetro de comparação) uma equivalência entre ambos.

Ainda sobre a sua dúvida, a verificação é feita através de um casting, uma vez que todas as classes herdam de `Object`, permitindo que seja possível a comparação desde que o objeto passado no parâmetro seja uma instância de `ExemploContaEquals`.

E caso exista a equivalência entre os dois atributos dos objetos utilizados na comparação, será retornado `true`, como resultado.

Já sobre a seguinte dúvida:

> Por que o if do método principal compara somente os dois últimos atributos dos objetos instanciados? ou seja só compara os números 20 e 21 dos objetos obj1 e obj2 respectivamente e os números 50 e 50 dos objetos obj3 e obj4.Qual a diferença então de ter dois atributos?

Neste caso, como o método está sendo sobrescrito, fica a cargo do desenvolvedor estipular o parâmetro que será levado em consideração na hora de realizar a comparação, propriamente dita.

Nesse exemplo mostrado, o autor preferiu utilizar o atributo `conta` como parâmetro, mas nada o impede de decidir alterar isso depois para a verificação por agência, por exemplo, ou então incluir os dois atributos como parâmetro de comparação.

Comment: Então os dois parâmetros servem para se no caso eu tiver um outro atributo? Por isso o this(0,0) no segundo construtor? agora entendi  acho que foi isso que me confundiu.

Comment: É como eu coloquei, o autor desejou criar um exemplo bastante didático, tentando elaborar um pouco e elencando algumas boas práticas de codificação. O `this(0,0)` é pra criar um objeto com os valores agência e conta não nulos, uma vez que não existe um método `set` para o atributo `conta`.

Answer (score 4):

O `Equals()` é um método que vem da classe `Object` e na sua assinatura espera um objeto do tipo `Object` como parâmetro.

Se a [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) fosse `equals(ExemploContaEquals obj)`, ele não seria o mesmo método herdado, a herança só ocorre quando a assinatura é exatamente igual.

Então é feito um *cast* para indicar ao compilador que pretende ler este objeto como se ele fosse um objeto do tipo `ExemploContaEquals` afinal você sabe que é isto que deseja. Se comparar um objeto `ExemploContaEquals` com um `Object`, o segundo não terá acesso aos membros de `ExemploContaEquals` mesmo que eles  estejam lá. O compilador proíbe o acesso aos membros que não sejam do tipo especificado. Quando você diz que ele é daquele tipo, aí o compilador permite.

Claro que para fazer isto sem dar erro precisa ter certeza que a "conversão" (não há uma conversão de fato) é possível e para isto existe o `if` anterior garantindo que o objeto é de um tipo compatível.

A segunda questão eu responderia: "porque o exemplo manda fazer isto", não parece ter um motivo especial. De qualquer forma o método tem que definir o que está sendo comparado. É uma decisão "de negócio" o que será usado, o que é relevante para a comparação. Concordo que a conta sozinha sem a agência é algo esquisito, mas é só um exemplo bobo, não vai rodar em um banco :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado ;)