# Equals e HashCode

Tags: java, lógica

Olá! Estou com uma dúvida conceitual. 
Tenho um método **readDao(tabela)** dentro do ObjectDAO (acesso ao banco) que retorna um HashSet chamado **resultadoRead** com todos os objetos no banco de dados daquela **tabela**. Tenho também um método **insertRule(Object obj)** dentro de uma ObjectRule(regra de negócio), que executa um método da ObjectDAO, após fazer a seguinte verificação:

```
 if (!resultadoRead.contains(obj)) {

 // executa a inserção do objeto no banco de dados.
 ObjectDAO.insertDAO(obj);
 }
```

Minha dúvida é: 
Para o contains funcionar, preciso implementar o hashset e o equals no Objeto ou na Classe DAO?
porque na classe DAO, não há atributos, apenas metodos. Os atributos pertencem ao Objeto.

Utilizo herança? outra forma de verificação? Abandono o java porque essa dúvida é muito idiota?

Comment: Talvez duplicata de [Como funciona o método equals?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111208/como-funciona-o-método-equals)

Comment: Outra: [Como sobrescrever método equals?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122981/28595)

Comment: Relacionada:[Qual a importância de implementar o método hashCode em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11108/28595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em teoria você não precisaria sobrescrever esses métodos para que o contains funcionasse. Por padrão, o `contains()` vai chamar o `equals()` do objeto passado por parâmetro que por sua vez vai usar o `hashCode()` para efetuar a comparação. Novamente, em teoria isso já deveria estar funcionando. 
Caso você realmente tenha necessidade de alterar o comportamento desses métodos, é necessário efetuar a mudança dentro da estrutura do objeto e não na sua classe DAO, afinal é o objeto que está sendo comparado.

Comment: perfeita explicação. Dúvida esclarecida! Muito obrigado!!