# Como funciona o método equals() em Java?

Tags: java, objetos, equals

Na hora que eu vou usar o método `equals()` eu coloco um objeto do tipo `Person` e ele funciona, por que?

Como ele funcionam sendo que o objeto que eu passei não é do tipo `Object`?

Eu sei que tudo isso tem haver com a classe `Object`.

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Person contaDiferente = (Person) obj;
    if (this.salario == contaDiferente.salario) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No java, todo objeto estende da classe [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: @NaranTeodoro, acredito que a resposta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789) pode ajudar na compreensão da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funciona porque qualquer instância/objeto do tipo `Person` (ou de qualquer outra classe) também é um `Object`.

De forma implícita, todas as classes Java herdam de `Object`.

Por isso que quando você acaba de criar uma classe ela já "vem com" os métodos:

```
clone()
equals(Object obj)
finalize()
getClass()
hashCode()
notify()
notifyAll()
toString()
wait()
wait(long timeout)
wait(long timeout, int nanos)
```

Pois esses são *herdados* da classe [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: então seu eu criar uma classe e as de mais (filhas) fazer um extends dela, eu posso fazer esse mesmo esquema, ou só funciona com a classe Objects ?

Comment: Pode fazer esse mesmo esquema. **Todas** classes em Java herdam de Object. Se o parâmetro do seu método for to tipo `Object` você pode passar qualquer tipo

Answer (score 7):

Isso chama-se polimorfismo. Veja a [definição deste conceito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101). Ele permite o reuso de código.

## Hierarquia de tipos

Então todos os tipos que você cria, no seu exemplo o `Person`, são ao mesmo tempo outros tipos. Pelo menos em Java sempre tem um outro tipo nos tipos por referência criados como uma classe.

Em Java só pode ter um tipo que herda uma estrutura de um tipo (classes), mas pode herdar de vários tipos que não formam um objeto completo ([interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101)), ou seja, que não tem estado ([variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)), só comportamentos ([métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212265/101)) e contratos ([assinatura de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101)).

Entenda a [diferença entre subclasse e subtipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101).

Para garantir que uma nova classe sempre tenha um tipo ele é implicitamente herdado de `Object`. Esse é o tipo raiz do Java, ele tem alguns métodos já implementados que o seu tipo sempre terá em função de ter herdado de `Object` (veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) quais são eles).

Um destes métodos é o [`equals()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111211/101). geralmente usamos o [`@override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/101).

Se você herdar de outro tipo ele não estará herdando diretamente de `Object`, mas indiretamente sim, porque se o seu tipo herda de um tipo (sempre classe) que deve obrigatoriamente ter herdado de `Object`, então na prática herda de `Object` também.

## Sobreposição

Claro que os métodos podem ter uma implementação diferente. O tipo que você está herdando pode ter sobreposto o que o `Object` fazia. Assim como o seu tipo pode sobrepor.

A [sobreposição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89309/101) é bastante útil para permitir que você execute o método de acordo com a necessidade do seu tipo.

## Polimorfismo aplicado

Então quando você for escrever um método que precise lidar com alguma característica de `Object` não precisa escrever um para cada tipo que criar, pode criar um que recebe um objeto qualquer, parâmetro declarado genericamente como `Object`, e ele consegue lidar com aquilo porque ele [é um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101) `Object`, além de ser o seu próprio tipo (`Person`). Ele pode ser outros tipos ao mesmo tempo também. Ou seja, ele pode assumir várias formas, ele tem várias facetas.

## *Casting*

Mas note que no seu caso só funciona porque está usando um *cast*. Você está acessando o membro `salario` de `obj`. Você sabe que `Person` tem esse membro. Mas ele está recebendo um `Object`, e você sabe que este tipo não tem o membro `salario`. A única forma do compilador aceitar que você acesse `salario` é se você transformar o objeto em `Person`. O `*cast*  faz isso.

Como dá certo? Porque o objeto concreto que foi passado para este método é um `Person`, ele recebe como `Object`, mas de fato é só uma faceta dele, existe uma "pessoa" ali dentro do objeto. Se tentar acessar um membro do `Object, funciona. Se tentar acessar um membro de` Person` não funciona, mesmo que você saiba que tem o membro lá. Você tem que instruir o compilador aceitar o que você deseja.

Mas pensa bem. E se você passar um `Object` mesmo, ou um `Product`, o que acontece com o código quando ele tenta fazer o *cast*? Ele tentará transformar um `Product` em `Person`. O objeto concreto recebido como `Object` não tem os membros de `Person` e o código falhará se tentar acessá-los.

Mas pode acontecer algo pior. Seu `Person` tem um `name` e o `Product` também tem um `name`. Mas são nomes bem diferentes, um de uma pessoa e o outro é de um produto, você não pode usar uma como se fosse o outro. Para isso definiu-se que sua aplicação já impede o erro no *casting* e um objeto do novo tipo não existirá. O *casting*  gerará um objeto nulo.

O correto é verificar se a transformação deu certo, caso contrário é um erro de programação seu.

Eu não gosto dessa forma de resolver as coisas, mas é a forma que o Java tem. É ineficiente, obriga tomar muitos cuidados e é fácil cometer um erro. Quebra a segurança de tipos que a linguagem propala como sendo um de seus trunfos.

Eu [respondi uma pergunta com um exemplo mais seguro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34564/101).

Seu código ficaria melhor assim:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // Um objeto é sempre igual a ele mesmo
    if (this == obj) return true; 
    // Um objeto nunca deve ser igual a null
    /* Uma pessoa só pode ser igual a outra pessoa.
     * Caso uma pessoa possa ser igual a uma de suas subclasses
     * use !(obj instanceof Person)
     */
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    // Converte a referencia para uma pessoa
    final Person other = (Person)obj;
    //alguma falhar ocorrer na transformação
    if (othe == null) return false;
    // Elas possuem o mesmo salario
    return this.salario == contaDiferente.salario;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/EqualsImplementation.java)

## Nem todos objetos em Java derivam de `Object`

Nem todos os objetos em Java derivam de `Object`, pelo menos até a versão 15 )ou superior, estão prometendo desde a 9). Algo vai mudar em Java futuro que terá a possibilidade de criar tipos por valor que derivam de `Object`. Não se sabe ainda se os tipos atuais por valor que não derivam de `Object` vão passar derivar ou não. Então um `Integer` deriva de `Object`, mas um `int` não deriva. Isso tem implicações importantes que não vem ao caso aqui.

## Conclusão

Alguma coisa me diz que este método está semanticamente errado. Isso não deveria comparar salários, ele deve estar preocupado com a identidade do objeto e salário não faz parte da sua identidade. E algo me diz que o [tipo de salário não é o adequado para guardar um valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101).

Cuidado com informações que pega na internet, você nunca sabe o comprometimento que o autor tem em passar informação correta para você, e ele não conhece bem o seu contexto. Por exemplo, eu não sei se entende tudo o que estou escrevendo, o que dá margem para novas perguntas, mas não posso escrever um livro completo sobre o assunto, vai aprendendo uma coisa por vez.

Answer (score 0):

No java, todo objeto estende da classe [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). Mesmo quando não utilizando explicitamente o `extends Object`, o Java, automaticamente, faz esse processo.

**Hierarquia de uma classe:**
[image: Hierarquia das classes no Java]

Essa classe raiz é definida no pacote `java.lang`, ela define e implementa os métodos [clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()), [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), [finalize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), [getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()), [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), [notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()), [notifyAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()), [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) e [wait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).