# Erro ao chamar add em um HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

Toda vez que tento criar um `objeto.add();` e coloco o atributo nele, ele continuar a me dar um erro. Veja o meu código:

```
public class Agencia {
    private String nome;
    private String endr;
    Set<Conta> listaContas = new HashSet<Conta>();

    private int nrAgencia;

    public Agencia(int pNrAgencia, String pNome, String pEndr){
        this.setNome(pNome);
        this.setEndr(pEndr);
        this.setNrAgencia(pNrAgencia);

        //AQUI ESTA
        //O Netbens me informa que ha um erro, e não consigo resolver
        listaContas.add(pNrAgencia);

    }

 //Outra Classe
 public class Conta {
      Conta(int pnrConta,  double pSaldo, Agencia agencia,Pessoa ptitular){
        System.out.println("Nome:");
        ptitular.setNome(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Endereço:");
        ptitular.setEndr(scan.nextLine());

        this.setNrConta(pnrConta);
        this.setSaldo(pSaldo);

        //Agencia
         System.out.println("Informe o numero da agencia");
        agencia.setNrAgencia(scan.nextInt());
    }

    public Conta() {

    }
```

Comment: `listaContas` é um `Set<Conta>`, então você só pode adicionar instâncias de `Conta` nele. Você tentou adicionar `pNrAgencia`, que é um `int` (e não uma `Conta`), por isso o erro.

Comment: no caso irei instanciar da classe conta, dentro da hashset ?

Comment: Você cria uma `Conta` e em seguida adiciona ela no `HashSet`

Comment: tem como fazer um pequeno exemplo simples, pq eu fiz isso e deu erro, possa ser que  eu nao esteja entendendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Agencia {
    private String nome;
    private String endr;
    Set<Conta> listaContas = new HashSet<Conta>();

    private int nrAgencia;

    public Agencia(int pNrAgencia, String pNome, String pEndr){
       Conta conta = new Conta();
        listaContas.add(conta); 
    //o Set não aceita duplicidade e não garante ordenação 
    // e também esta tipado para receber o tipo conta então ele deve receber conta

    }
```

Comment: eu te amo cara, muito muito muito obrigado

Comment: @Vitor Só um detalhe, `new Conta()` cria uma conta "vazia" (sem os campos preenchidos, portanto sem número, saldo, agência e titular). Faz sentido criar uma conta vazia e adicioná-la em `listaContas` quando vc cria uma agência? Ao criar uma agência, ela pode começar sem nenhuma conta, e `new HashSet` já inicializa `listaContas`, então nem precisaria criar e adicionar a conta vazia. Até mesmo o construtor sem parâmetros é algo a ser avaliado, entenda melhor lendo este link:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052

Comment: @Vitor Outro detalhe é que recomenda-se que objetos que são adicionados em um `HashSet` implementem `equals` e `hashcode`. Entenda melhor lendo [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11108/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122978/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111208/112052)