# Por que é possível definir dois ou mais métodos com o mesmo nome na mesma classe em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, característica-linguagem, método

Estou iniciando meus estudos no C# com ASP.NET MVC hoje. Estou ainda me adaptando com algumas coisas que não estou acostumado a ver, pois conheço linguagens como PHP, Python e JavaScript.

Percebi que em um código que já veio pronto, ao iniciar um projeto ASP.NET MVC com Razor, que alguns métodos da classe `AccountController.cs`, por exemplo, são declarado duas vezes.

Não entendi por que é possível definir um método com o mesmo nome duas vezes.

Como eu estou acostumado com outras linguagens, gostaria de uma explicação sobre isso.

Exemplo do código que está no meu projeto:

```
  // GET: /Account/SendCode
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
    {
        var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
        if (userId == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var userFactors = await UserManager.GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync(userId);
        var factorOptions = userFactors.Select(purpose => new SelectListItem { Text = purpose, Value = purpose }).ToList();
        return View(new SendCodeViewModel { Providers = factorOptions, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/SendCode
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SendCode(SendCodeViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // Generate the token and send it
        if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(model.SelectedProvider))
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = model.SelectedProvider, ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    }
```

Ou seja, a declaração de `SendCode` é feita duas vezes.

Qual é o significado dessa "duplicação" do nome dos métodos?

Isso tem alguma coisa a ver com polimorfismo ou algo semelhante?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Termo

Isto é chamado de [sobrecarga de função](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecarga) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) bem melhor). É algo bastante comum em linguagens estaticamente tipadas. Ele existe em linguagens de diversos paradigmas e não é uma característica da orientação a objeto, como muitos acreditam.

Talvez por `override` se "assemelhar" com `overload` as pessoas acham que é a mesma coisa. Conheço muito programador "experiente" que erra isso.

Outro motivo para a confusão é que também existe a [sobrecarga de operador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading). É um mecanismo diferente do que está sendo tratado aqui. É [um tipo de polimorfismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism) e costuma ser usado em orientação a objeto.

## Funcionamento

Isto é uma característica geral dos métodos de todo tipo, normais, virtuais, estáticos, construtores, não importa que tecnologia ou aplicação esteja usando. Por isso a documentação costuma fornecer mais de uma versão dela.

Em geral os métodos de mesmo nome fazem algo muito semelhante e tem o mesmo objetivo. É só um facilitador para o programador lembrar das diversas formas possíveis e um IDE poder ajudar mostrando as diversas assinaturas dele.

As linguagens que não possuem esse recurso tem que dar um nome diferente para cada método que tenha parâmetros diferentes. O que dificulta nomear e até incentiva nomes ruins, chegando ao ponto de usarem `fazAlgo1()`, `fazAlgo2()`, etc.

Os métodos são desambiguados pela sua [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) (os detalhes estão aí no *link*), ou seja, pelos tipos dos parâmetros. Por isso o recurso não faz sentido em linguagens dinamicamente tipadas.

Cada linguagem possui um mecanismo específico para selecionar qual é o método mais adequado. O C# não considera o tipo do retorno, tem linguagem que considera (até os nomes dos parâmetros ou outras características do contrato). O compilador decide qual opção destes métodos chamar dependendo do tipo de cada parâmetro. Essa escolha costuma ser chamada de *betterness* (o que melhor se encaixa) e é algo extremamente complexo por causa da hierarquia de tipos.

É claro que internamente o nome é modificado para facilitar o compilador. Não pode ter dois métodos com mesmo nome. Assim como já não poderia ter, mesmo em classes diferentes, que também tem seu nome modificado internamente. Já falei isso em algumas respostas.

## Exemplo

```
SendCode("http://www.dominio.com", true)
```

chama o primeiro. Para chamar o segundo seria:

```
SendCode(new SendCodeViewModel()) //só pra exemplificar.
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Signature.cs).

No ASP.NET MVC tem uma importância extra porque o método pode ser uma ação do controlador, então parte da rota determinará qual método chamar, mas isso se dará pelo nome e pelos dados que está indo junto em uma requisição HTTP.

Olha só quantos [construtores diferentes tem a classe `String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#constructors). Tudo o mesmo nome (claro), mas cada um opera de um jeito diferente). [O mesmo vale para os métodos regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#methods). Veja a lista que tem vários nomes duplicados. Mas nenhum com a mesma assinatura. Note na lista da documentação que além do nome consta os tipos para diferenciá-los.

Por isso em uma herança ou implementação de uma interface é preciso cuidado porque o método a ser herdado não basta ter só o mesmo nome, tem que ter a exata assinatura que seu superior.

## Alternativa

O C# possui o recurso de valor *default* para os parâmetros, o que torna a necessidade da sobrecarga bem menor. Ou seja, se for só para colocar um valor em um parâmetro não precisa fazer isso. Normalmente é necessário apenas nos casos onde há uma lógica diferente entre um método e outro.

Answer (score 7):

Esta "duplicação" é o que chamamos de sobrecarga de métodos. Uma característica presente em linguagens orientadas a objeto.

Apesar do nome ser igual, como no seu exemplo `SendCode`, as assinaturas dos métodos são diferentes, com parâmetros específicos em cada declaração.

A partir dos parâmetros informados na chamada do método o compilador pode definir qual método executar.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode definir o método com o mesmo nome se o método receber tipos de parâmetros diferente.

Perceba que o método `SendCode(string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)` recebe dois parâmetros, e o `SendCode(SendCodeViewModel model)` recebe outro tipo de parâmetro, sendo assim você pode ter mais de um método com o mesmo nome, porém se os dois métodos recebessem o mesmo tipo de parâmetros, você iria ter um erro.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.