# Error 1 No overload for method 'MétodoHerdado ' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sobrecarga

> Error 1 No overload for method 'MétodoHerdado ' takes 1 arguments

**Código:**

```
    public void restauraRegistro(DataGridViewRow linha)
    {
        
        try
        {
            string codigo = String.Empty;

            
            //verifica se e para recuperar com outro codigo
            if (this.checkRecuperaOutroCodigo.Checked)
                codigo = this.conexaoBanco.proximoCodigo(this.tabela).ToString(); //Limha do erro

                
            MySqlCommand sql = this.conexaoBanco.criaComandoSQL ("sp_restaura_registro");
            sql.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sp_codigo", linha.Cells["codigo"].Value));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sp_tabela", this.tabela));
            sql.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("sp_codigo_novo", codigo));

            this.conexaoBanco.executaQuery(sql);
            //remove do datagrid a linha
            this.gridRegistrosDeletados.Rows.RemoveAt(linha.Index);
            this.removeuRegistro = true;
        }

        catch (MySqlException erro)
        {
            this.removeuRegistro = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao restaurar o registro.\nErro: " + erro.Message, "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Método chamado

```
/// <summary>
    /// Retorna o próximo codigo da tabela
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tb">Nome da Tabela</param>
    /// <param name="pk">Nome do Campo</param>
    /// <returns>inteiro proximo codigo</returns>
    public int proximoCodigo(string tb, string pk)
    {
        int resultado = 0;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("sp_proximo_codigo", objConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_data_base", "folha"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_tabela", tb));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("_campo", pk));

        if (!this.OpenConnection())
            return 0;

        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
            resultado = int.Parse(dataReader["retorno"].ToString());

        dataReader.Close();
        this.CloseConnection();

        return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Verifique a assinatura do método `proximoCodigo`, de certeza que não recebe um parâmetro (pode receber mais ou menos).

Comment: Estou com esse erro, auguem pode me ajudar :(

Comment: ERRO: Error 1 No overload for method 'MétodoHerdado ' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Dentro do método `proximoCodigo` está a evocar esse método? Verifique a assinatura de ambos os métodos.

Comment: Bolas, nem vi que o método `proximoCodigo` estava no seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa linha

```
 codigo = this.conexaoBanco.proximoCodigo(this.tabela)
```

Vc está chamando o método passando 1 parâmetro `(this.tabela)`

E como o erro diz, seu método espera duas strings

```
 public int proximoCodigo(string tb, string pk)
```

Pelo summary ali em cima, pode ser que seja `this.tabela.Nome` e `this.tabela.Campo` as strings que vc tem que passar.

Verifique a assinatura, vê se não tem nenhum overload que receba só 1. Ou para usar esse mesmo, passe as duas strings.

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado !!!

Answer (score 5):

Em primeiro lugar sugiro procurar um livro, um curso, porque está fazendo um código bem complexo sem entender o que está ocorrendo nele, isso não dá certo, você está se enganado e está cometendo erros que não são perceptíveis por não entender. O código está cheio de erros, mas ele vai funcionar, até que um dia falhará e nem saberá porque. Programação é muito mais complicado do que você imagina e está errando em coisas básicas.

O seu erro específico que por sorte deu erro explícito e te proibiu de fazer errado tem a ver com uma coisa chamada [*overload* de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137185/101). Os métodos podem ter mais de uma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), mas neste caso a mensagem de erro é genérica, nem precisa ter mais um, o fato de só ter 1 já basta para dar o erro quando a chamada não bate com a definição do método.

Note que você escreveu um método com 2 parâmetros, ambos recebendo uma `string`, uma parece ser o nome da tabela e outra a chave primária (péssimos nomes de variáveis). Quando você faz a chamada está passando apenas `this.tabela`, ou seja, só um argumento. Então não tem como resolver. Precisa passar uma outra `string*  para chamar o método correto. O compilador se confunde achando que deveria ter uma método com apenas 1 parâmetro. A solução exata não sabemos porque não tem no código algo que sabemos ser o campo.

De qualquer forma eu não faria o que está tentando fazer, principalmente sem entender todas consequências disso. Já parece ser uma bela gambiarra no banco de dados, mas não tenho todos os dados para afirmar. A própria ideia de ter alguma coisa que pega o próximo código está conceitualmente errada e causará problemas em ambiente de concorrência. Você ficará desesperado quando isso começar dar erros que parecem aleatórios e não conseguirá ajuda para resolvê-lo.

Entenda [Por que é possível definir dois ou mais métodos com o mesmo nome na mesma classe em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131023/101).

Comment: Então amigo, foi mais uma falta de atenção minha, eu apaguei sem querer

Comment: public int proximoCodigo(string tb, string pk = "id_inss")

Comment: Que era pré definido, mas de qualquer forma muito obrigado !!!

Comment: O sistema tem uma "lixeira de dados", e é possível recuperar o dado usando outro código... Somente por isso o próximo código.

Comment: Subentendo que não é a forma correta de funcionamento, mas é o que me foi pedido basicamente

Comment: @vinibsc me desculpe, mas duvido que alguém pediu para fazer tudo errado, mas claro você faz como quiser.