# Por que uma Trait não pode implementar uma interface?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface, herança, trait

Por que uma Trait não pode implementar uma interface no PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Permitir que um *trait* implemente uma interface faz todo sentido para mim. Podemos encarar o *trait* como uma interface que tem implementação, e não tem estado, ao contrário da classe abstrata. Sendo assim se uma interface pode estender outra (obviamente não podem implementar, porque interfaces não implementam), por que um *trait* não pode tanto estender quanto implementar interfaces?

Existe um motivo. *Traits* podem renomear métodos. Interfaces são contratos. Elas devem garantir que um método tenha implementação dentro da classe. O *trait* normalmente garantiria pelo simples fato dele já implementar o método. Mas se ele for renomeado, mesmo que a implementação esteja lá, ele não poderá ser acessado como a interface requer. Mudou o nome do método implementado, mudou a [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) dele e não atende mais ao contrato.

Se não tivesse a possibilidade de renomear, acho que poderia existir essa possibilidade. Mas aí *traits* poderiam ter colisões insolúveis. Em tese é possível ter soluções de colisão sem ter um *rename*, mas criaria alguma limitação que pode ser bem ruim para alguns casos e tornaria *traits* menos úteis.

O que pode fazer é declarar a interface na classe. Se não tiver *rename* de método, o *trait* já resolve o contrato. Se tiver *rename* é porque tem outro método que já atende a interface, e pode até fazer uma delegação.

Em PHP tem um complicador extra que exige renomear porque a assinatura só considera o nome do método e não seus parâmetros.

Para evitar complicação eles preferiram não ter uma regra cheia de exceções.

Mas dá para contornar nos casos que faça sentido:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    public function someInterfaceFunction();
}

trait SomeTrait {
    function sayHello() {
        echo "Hello my secret is ".static::$secret;
    }
}

abstract class AbstractClass implements SomeInterface {
    use SomeTrait;
}

class TestClass extends AbstractClass {
    static public  $secret = 12345;
    function someInterfaceFunction(){ }
}
$test = new TestClass();
$test->sayHello();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/h9wL7i). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rfravqtz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/TraitInterface.php).

Retirei o exemplo de uma [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14866251/221800) que não acho que diz bem qual é o problema.