# Devo utilizar classe abstrata ou interface?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface, classes-abstratas

Tenho uma classe que realiza conexão a máquinas Windows. Estou deixando ela um pouco mais genérica, de modo que eu possa reaproveitar para outros sistemas.

Logo consegui identificar quatro métodos "genéricos":

- conectar
- status
- mensagemErro
- executar

Com isso, montei uma classe e uma interface, mas minha dúvida é a seguinte: No cenário abaixo, é melhor utilizar uma classe abstrata, ou uma interface é mais que suficiente?

Classe de conexão:

```
class Windows implements Conector
{
    /**
     * Armazena um apontamento externo para um recurso
     * 
     * @access private
     * @var object
     */
    private static $conexao;

    /**
     * Armazena a(s) mensagens de erro
     * 
     * @access private
     * @var string
     */
    private static $mensagemErro;

    /**
     * Método de conexão
     * 
     * @param   string $host
     * @param   string $usuario
     * @param   string $senha
     * @param   int $porta
     * @param   int $timeout
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function conectar($host, $usuario = null, $senha = null, $porta = 135, $timeout = 10)
    {
        try
        {
            /**
             * Método utilizado para testar conectividade com o host alvo
             * 
             * @param string $host
             * @param string $porta
             * @param int    $errno valor de sistema
             * @param string $errstr mensagem de sistema
             * @param int    $timeout tempo máximo a esperar por uma tentativa de conexão via socket
             */    
            if (!@fsockopen($host, $porta, $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ({$errno}): Time Out ao chamar o host <b>{$host}</b>!");
            }

            //...

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            self::$mensagemErro =  $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static function status()
    {
        return (self::$conexao !== NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    public static function mensagemErro()
    {
        return self::$mensagemErro;
    }

    public static function executar($acao)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!self::$conexao)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro: É necessário abrir uma conexão antes de tentar executar qualquer comando!");
            }
             // @see http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php
            return self::$conexao->ExecQuery($query);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
interface Conector
{
    /**
     * Método de conexão para máquinas Windows
     * 
     * @param   string $host
     * @param   string $usuario
     * @param   string $senha
     * @param   int $porta
     * @param   int $timeout
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function conectar($host, $usuario = null, $senha = null, $porta = 135, $timeout = 10);

    public static function status();

    public static function mensagemErro();

    public static function executar($acao);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @bigown. Já subi o projeto: https://github.com/crphp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quiser fazer certo, nenhum dos dois. Pelo menos com os nomes usados. Uma classe chamada `Windows`, que já acho estranho, não parece que deveria herdar ou implementar um `Conector`. Isso parece erro de *design*.

Mas se quiser insistir a [interface deveria ser preferida sempre que possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101). Parece que nesse caso é possível, então deveria fazer assim mesmo.

Se quisesse ter implementações padrões nesses métodos aí a interface não seria mais possível. Mas um `trait` poderia ser a solução (tem [pergunta sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101), [outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157720/101)).

Se precisar de estados (variáveis) e não só comportamentos (métodos), aí só [a classe abstrata resolverá](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101). Pensando bem, a classe que implementa a interface teve que criar variáveis. Era isso que desejava? Deixar todos detalhes de implementação para a classe decidir como fazer? Se foi isso, ótimo. Se não era a intenção, se queria já fornecer dessa forma implementada na classe, e quem sabe deixar a classe sobrepor, ou não, aí a classe deveria ser abstrata, no mínimo.

Se todos os comportamentos forem implementados nessa classe e acha que é útil ela ser instanciada por si só em alguma situação, aí a [classe deve ser concreta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89236/101).

Mais uma [pergunta já feita responde isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101) (já existia outra, siga os *links*).

## Adendo

Todos esses membros estáticos parecem ser um erro. Se é para fazer isso, faça tudo procedural, não vi vantagem fazer desta forma.

Considero o uso da exceção aí de forma equivocada, mas isso é algo que eu quase desisti, quase todo mundo faz errado. [Já falei muito sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D), não vou repetir aqui. Na verdade esse foi uma dos maiores abusos que já vi em códigos. Nesse caso ela não só é errada, é completamente desnecessária.

O método `status` está fazendo algo redundante.

Ou seja, parece que está tentando pegar um conceito avançado quando ainda não domina aspectos básicos da linguagem. Eu não iria por esse caminho. Mas quase ninguém ouve.

Assim como [fazer OOP em exagero em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108227/101). Veja também: [PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).