# Como é feita a verificação de assinatura da função super

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem, método, herança

A função `super()` serve para chamar o construtor pai e verificar assinaturas adequadas.

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String cpf;
    private String telefoneCelular;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String endereco, String telefone) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
}

public class Aluno extends Pessoa {

    public Aluno() {
        super();
    }

    public Aluno(String curso, double[] notas, String nome, String endereco, String telefone) {
        super(nome, endereco, telefone);
        this.curso = curso;
        this.notas = notas;
    }
}
```

Embora saiba que funcione desta maneira, não compreendo como é feita a verificação de assinatura quando as variáveis de escopo são diferentes.

```
public class Aluno extends Pessoa {

    public Aluno() {
        super();
    }

    public Aluno(String curso, double[] notas, String teste1, String teste2, String teste3) {
        super(teste1, teste2, teste3);
        this.curso = curso;
        this.notas = notas;
    }
}
```

A verificação se daria pela ordem em que as variáveis são declaradas dentro da função super?, pois todas são do mesmo tipo (`String`).

1. teste1 = nome
2. teste2 = endereco
3. teste3 = telefone

Comment: Exatamente, se você passar teste2 como nome, teste1 como telefone e teste3 como endereço, as atribuições serão feitas "erradas", porque a sua implementação foi feita assim. O java não verifica relacao do nome que você deu ao atribulo ao seu tipo, se o tipo bater, ele vai atribuir o valor, se não, ele nem deixa compilar.

Comment: Então a ordem que eu declarar elas dentro de Aluno(...) não irá importar, apenas será de importância a declaração dentro da função super()?.

Comment: Se você alterar a ordem dos argumentos do construtor de aluno em nada afeta os do super, desde que na implementação dentro do construtor de aluno, você passe corretamente os argumentos para o super().

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Assinaturas de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) só consideram a quantidade e os tipos dos parâmetros em sua ordem específica, além, de obviamente o nome do método, os nomes deles não importam. Então se você tiver dois métodos com mesmo nome e ambos tem três parâmetros do tipo `String`, dará erro, porque a assinatura é a mesma, mesmo que os nomes dos parâmetros sejam outros.

Você é responsável por usar o método da forma correta, como já foi dito nos comentários.

Se for muito importante não ter confusão tem uma técnica que eu não acho boa na maioria das situações. Se for usar só para isto não recomendo.

Crie classes para cada um desses membros, aí você terá 3 tipos diferentes. Algo assim:

```
public class Nome {
    private String nome;
    //e todo os resto aqui, construtor, métodos acessadores, operações, validações, etc.
}
public class Endereco {
    private String endereco;
    //e todo os resto aqui, construtor, métodos acessadores, operações, validações, etc.
}
public class Telefone {
    private String telefone;
    //e todo os resto aqui, construtor, métodos acessadores, operações, validações, etc.
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Signarure.java).