# O que significa construtores com this?

Tags: c#, .net, construtor

Esse construtor tem um `this`, o que realmente significa?

```
public class HelpController : Controller
{
    private const string ErrorViewName = "Error";

    public HelpController()
        : this(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }

    public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }

    public HttpConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.DocumentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
        return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
    }

    public ActionResult Api(string apiId)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(apiId))
        {
            HelpPageApiModel apiModel = Configuration.GetHelpPageApiModel(apiId);
            if (apiModel != null)
            {
                return View(apiModel);
            }
        }

        return View(ErrorViewName);
    }

    public ActionResult ResourceModel(string modelName)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName))
        {
            ModelDescriptionGenerator modelDescriptionGenerator = Configuration.GetModelDescriptionGenerator();
            ModelDescription modelDescription;
            if (modelDescriptionGenerator.GeneratedModels.TryGetValue(modelName, out modelDescription))
            {
                return View(modelDescription);
            }
        }

        return View(ErrorViewName);
    }
}
```

Veja a classe completa. Ele herda do construtor que está abaixo dele? Entendi mais ou menos o que os colegas responderam, mas fica ainda uma dúvida: por que o `this` tem isso: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. Ttalvez eu esteja com dúvida na nomenclatura.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode chamar outros construtores sobrecarregados dentro de um construtor, você só pode indicar que ele deve ser chamado, assim o compilador colocar a chamada no local mais adequado.

No caso ele está chamando o outro construtor que tem um parâmetro e já passando um valor padrão:

```
public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config) => Configuration = config;
```

o parâmetro `config` receberá `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` ´passado no outro construtor.

Não é bem assim, mas esse construtor seria o mesmo que escrever isto:

```
public HelpController() => this.HelpController(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Isto é chamado de inicializador. Isto é útil quando tem algo precise ser adicionado ao comportamento a um construtor que já está presente em outro construtor (sobrecarga de dele)). Nesse exemplo, o construtor foi criado para dar uma facilidade, ter um construtor que não precisa passar nada que ele escolhe um valor padrão.

Se isto é uma enumeração poderia ser usado o valor *default*  para o parâmetro. Algo assim:

```
public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/This.cs).

Apenas para complementar, não para este código, tem casos que pode ser usado o `: base` no lugar do `: this`, aí ele chamará o construtor da classe base a esta. Exemplo: `public HelpController() : base(passa alguma coisa aqui)`. Note que sempre que há herança na classe o construtor *default* da classe base é chamada implicitamente, se o seu código não explicitar. Então mesmo que não esteja vendo quando faz `public HelpController()`, na verdade está fazendo `public HelpController() : base()`.

Já usei sintaxe do C# 7 para construtores de uma linha.

[O que é a assinatura de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101)

Comment: Big, fiz uma edição e veja a minha dúvida lá, por favor.

Comment: Esse construtor com o `: this()` é algo novo? Nunca soube disso, eu sempre criava um método privado chamado `Inicializa()` que eu chamava em todos os construtores (normalmente eu não uso mais do que 2 construtores, mas só fazia isso para facilitar).

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro(após a última edição), entendi o porquê disso, do `this`. Valeu e obrigado.

Comment: @Alisson desde a versão 1.0 :)

Answer (score 4):

É como se esse construtor "herdasse" outro construtor da mesma classe:

Exemplo:

```
    public PessoaRepositorio() : this("teste")
    {

    }
    public PessoaRepositorio(string a)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Na verdade não está herdando nada aí. O fato da sintaxe ser parecida não quer dizer que isto tenha qualquer relação com herança.