# É possivel oferecer opções de retorno num método?

Tags: c#, .net, método, return

Como já é do meu conhecimento existe o [*overload*](https://www.dotnetperls.com/overload) na criação dos métodos, que são opções de execução, exemplo(bem simples), um método onde você tem a opção de passar 2 ou 3 parâmetros chamando a mesma função:

```
//Soma 2 numeros
public int  Somar(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}    

//Soma 3 numeros
public int  Somar(int a,int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

A pergunta é: Eu posso criar um overload de retorno? Como por exemplo:

```
public PessoaJuridica RetornarPessoa(string id)
{
    return new PessoaJuridica();
}

public PessoaFisica RetornarPessoa(string id)
{
    return new PessoaFisica();
}
```

Surgiu a necessidade pois eu tenho dois método com nomes diferentes e seria mais fácil para mim usar o mesmo nome, pois eles fazem "a mesma coisa".

Comment: como você separa pessoa física de pessoa jurídica, digo, no banco de dados, estão em tabelas separadas ?

Comment: Rovann, foi um exemplo só, eu não estou utilizando PessoaF e PessoaJ, é que eu tenho dois tipos de usuario, o Usuario comum(que consulta fotos) e um usuario contribuidor(que envia), e eu queria receber os dados do perfil de ambos através de um nome de método apenas e não dois.

Comment: certo, então, esses dois tipos de usuários, estão na mesma tabela ? há um campo que identifique de qual tipo ele é ?

Comment: Estão em tabelas diferentes, porque nesse caso as informações de cada um são BEEEM diferentes. Digamos que seja outra área do site, eles não tem relação entre sí.

Comment: nesse caso, iria pelo generics mesmo, se tivesse uma relação de herança, até poderia usar o polimorfismo, mas se não tem relação, utilizaria de uma interface e método genérico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível. A assinatura do método **não considera** o tipo de retorno. Se fosse possível, complicaria o trabalho do compilador para saber qual método você quer usar.

Eu não entendo bem qual a intenção de se fazer isso e não há detalhes suficientes para eu poder entender, mas imagino que você possa resolver isso usando um método genérico.

```
public static T RetornarPessoa<T>(string id) where T: new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Eu **suponho** que você tenha alguma hierarquia nas classes. Por isso, fiz este exemplo de como pode ser implementada a minha ideia:

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DKuWjj)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pessoa = RetornarPessoa<PessoaFisica>("a550");
        Console.WriteLine(pessoa.Id);
    }

    public static T RetornarPessoa<T>(string id) where T: Pessoa, new()
    {

        return new T { Id = id };
    }
}

public abstract class Pessoa
{       
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaJuridica : Pessoa
{
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
}

public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
{
    public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Isto não é possível, a [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) só considere o seu nome e os tipos dos parâmetros.

Se fizesse com o retorno complicaria o compilador, criaria ambiguidade e possíveis *bugs*.

A solução mais sensata neste caso é colocar um diferencial no nome do método indicando qual é o tipo de retorno que ele proverá. Fica até mais legível. Cheguei pensar em algumas outras, mas nada que seja recomendado. Cheguei até iniciar uma resposta com uma alternativa, mas é algo que complica o código, cria confusão, abre brecha para *bugs*, melhor ir para o caminho fácil, seguro e óbvio.

```
public PessoaJuridica RetornarPessoaJuridica(string id) {
    return new PessoaJuridica();
}

public PessoaFisica RetornarPessoaFisica(string id) {
    return new PessoaFisica();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReturnDifferentType.cs).

Comment: seu post/resposta no link ficou fantástico !

Answer (score 2):

Na postagem foram feitas duas perguntas.

> Eu posso criar um overload de retorno?

**Não**, isso realmente não pode. A identidade de um método é feito por nome do método x parâmetros. Mesmo que duplique o método modificando apenas o retorno, o compilador vai entender que é o mesmo método - e não uma sobrecarga - e irá dar erro.

> É possível oferecer opções de retorno num método?

**É possível sim**, basta deixar isso claro na assinatura do método.

Um método pode ou não retornar um *valor*, mas o legal é que esse *valor* pode ser *qualquer coisa*.

### Usando [Either](https://github.com/ElemarJR/ElemarJR.FunctionalCSharp/blob/master/src/ElemarJR.FunctionalCSharp/Either.cs)

```
public interface IPessoaRepository
{
    Either<Option<PessoaFisica>, Option<PessoaJuridica>> RetornaPessoa(string id);
}

public class PessoaRepository : IPessoaRepository
{
    public Either<Option<PessoaFisica>, Option<PessoaJuridica>> RetornaPessoa(string id)
    {
        // { seu codigo aqui }
        return pessoa; // Tanto faz se é tipo PessoaFisica ou PessoaJuridica
    }
}
```

Fonte: http://www.elemarjr.com/pt/2017/04/exceptions-sao-muito-intrusivas/