# Alterar tipo de retorno

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Como faço para alterar o tipo de retorno de uma função de classe mãe na classe filha?
Por exemplo:

```
class Mother {
  public:
    void Get() {}
};

template <typename Type>
class Child : public Mother {
  public:
    Type Get() {
        // TODO
    }
};

int main()
{
    Mother* m_ptr = new Child<int>();

    auto x = ((Child<>)m_ptr)->Get();
}
```

Assim, ao acessar a função `Get()` de `m_ptr`, deve ser **implicitamente** retornado um valor `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Não faz, se a [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) é diferente então eles são completamente diferentes e não há herança entre eles a não ser que [o tipo seja covariante](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors), o que não é o caso. Se haverá herança deve respeitar o contrato.

Comment: Em c++ o tipo de retorno não faz parte da assinatura do método. E sim, em alguns casos, é válido ter assinaturas diferentes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665117/c-virtual-function-return-type

Comment: Se a assinatura for diferente, funcionará?

Comment: @FelipeNascimento dentro do que você propôs, não, é possível se mudar completamente o jeito de fazer tudo, mas aí não tem mais o problema que você descreveu na pergunta, passa ser outra coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) para resolver o problema, só que os tipos tem que ser conhecidos em tempo de compilação. Por exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename> class CLASS, typename T>
class Mother
{
public:
    T get() const { return static_cast<const CLASS<T>*>(this)->get();}
};

template <typename T>
class Child: public Mother<Child, T>
{
public:
    Child(T x) : v{x} {}
    T get() const {return v;}

    T v;
};

// Função criada só para mostrar a herança estática funcionando
template <template <typename> class CLASS, typename T>
T doit(const Mother<CLASS, T>& x)
{
    return x.get();
}

int main()
{
    auto f = Child<float>(6.6); // f é do tipo Child<float>
    auto c = Child<int>(5);      // c é do tipo Child<int>
    Mother<Child, int> m = c;   // m é do tipo Mother<Child, int>

    std::cout << doit(c) << std::endl;
    std::cout << doit(f) << std::endl;
}
```

Note que agora você pode chamar a função `doit` mesmo que os tipos de retorno sejam diferentes

Veja funcionando no [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e2e00d5e27b79ce)

Comment: Como você colocou `Mother<Child, int>`, funcionará apenas para números?

Comment: @FelipeNascimento Como tinha dito no início, vc tem que conhecer os tipos em tempo de compilação, i.e., `Mother<Child, int>` tem como filho `Child<int>`, enquanto que `Mother<Child, char>` tem como filho `Child<char>`. Embora pareça uma limitação, na prática não o é devido ao fato que a maioras das aplicações as usa como interface de funções, conforme vc pode ver na implementação da função `doit`. Devido ao sistema de _template_ a função é instanciada para cada tipo que é passada, tornado-a transparente aos tipos