# Sobrescrita de métodos de uma interface

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface, sobrescrita

Estou tendo uma dúvida quanto a sobrescrita de métodos de uma interface. Eu posso sobrescrever um método em uma classe filha que herda da classe mãe a implementação de uma interface e nesse método utilizar o recebimento de parâmetros?

Interface:

```
public interface Pagavel {
    public abstract double getValorAPagar();
}
```

Classe Mãe:

```
public abstract class Conta implements Pagavel {
    public abstract double getValorAPagar();
}
```

Classe Filha:

```
public class Titulo extends Conta{
    public double getValorAPagar(int param1, int param2){
       // implementação.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pode porque são métodos completamente diferentes. Só é o mesmo método se a [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) for exatamente a mesma e só pode sobrescrever o mesmo método.

Comment: Compreendo. Muito Obrigado.