# Polimorfismo de sobreposição é obrigatório?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo

Em polimorfismo de sobreposição é obrigatório que o método de uma classe mãe que será sobreposto em uma subclasse seja abstrato? Existe exceção para alguma linguagem POO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é obrigado e é bastante comum que não seja. A única exigência é que ele tenha a mesma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

Algumas linguagens podem ter uma assinatura que só considere o nome do método, o que fica muito fácil.

Cada linguagem pode fazer como quiser, mas desconheço alguma que exija isto.

O que existe é que em determinada construção em algumas linguagens, como a interface, exija que o método seja abstrato, mas não em uma classe mãe. C++ não tem tem interfaces.

É claro que todo método abstrato precisa ser sobreposto. Até poderia não exigir, mas aí não teria propósito ter todo este mecanismo.