# Como funciona o polimorfismo de sobrecarga em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, polimorfismo, sobrecarga

Recentemente aprendi POO em Java e agora estou aprendendo em Python. Há polimorfismo de sobrecarga (implementar métodos com nomes iguais na mesma classe, que dependendo dos parâmetros que você entrega para o método, ele chama um ou outro)?

Caso não haja, qual seria a alternativa a isso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Por padrão não há isso em Python  - Sendo uma linguagem dinâmica a abordagem é completamente diferente:

Tudo em Python é um objeto derivado da classe `object` - e a linguagem não checa o tipo de nenhum argumento em nenhuma chamada de função (mas a quantidade, e nome dos argumentos, sim).

Então num exemplo simples:

```
def soma(a, b):
   return a + b
```

Essa função vai ser chamada para quaisquer valores de a e b. Se forem números, eles serão somados. Se forem texto (string), a string será concatenada (já que para strings, o operador "+" é sobrecarregado para efetuar concatenação), e o método funciona do mesmo jeito. 
Já se você passar objetos que não implementam a operação de soma com o operador "+" (para suportar o operador, a classe do objeto tem que ter um método com o nome especial `__add__`), você obterá um `TypeError` em tempo de execução.

Isso é, em Python a linguagem não faz verificação de tipagem, e te dá flexibilidade para executar as mesmas operações e chamar funções com vários tipos de objeto diferentes, desde que eles "funcionem" da forma que a função chamada espera (nesse caso da `soma` um dos dois tem que ter um método `__add__` ou `__radd__` que reconheça o outro objeto passado).

Nada impede que você faça a checagem manual dentro do método ou função com `if` usando `isnstance` ou `issubclass` para determinar se os objetos passados tem os comportamentos necessários implementados - mas isso raramente é feito. De qualquer forma, a recomendação é testar o comportamento, e não a classe - por exemplo, vamos supor uma função que receba um objeto que pode ou não conter texto, mas se contiver, deve tentar converte-lo para maiúsculas com seu próprio método `.upper()` -  a forma poderia ser:

```
def generate_slug(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, "upper"):
        obj = obj.upper()
...
```

Em detrimento de:

```
def generate_slug(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        obj = obj.upper()
    ...
```

Com isso você resolve tudo o que conseguiria com polimorfismo variando os tipos dos argumentos passados. Agora há uma outra característica realmente muito útil em Python que são os parâmetros opcionais:

```
def soma3(a, b, c=0):
    return a + b + c
```

Veja nessa declaração - com o `=` é especifícado um valor padrão para  `c`: ou seja `soma3` pode ser chamado com 2 ou 3 argumentos. Se só dois forem usados, `c` retem o valor `0`. Caso seja passados 3 valores, o terceiro é usado para `c`.

Há ainda sintaxes que permitem um número indeterminado de parâmetros em sequência (para os quais não importa o nome, apenas a ordem), e uma quantidade indeterminada de parâmetros com nome -

```
def soma_n(*args):
   acc = 0
   for arg in args:
      acc += arg
   return acc

soma_n(5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Sugiro buscar uma leitura suplementar sobre parâmetros com nome, e com mais exemplos de uso de *args e **kwargs  - são tópicos bem importantes mas não diretamente relacionados com a questão do polimorfismo.

Então até aqui temos que: uma única função pode receber argumentos de tipos variados, e um número variado de parâmetros - em contraste com linguagens estaticamente tipadas implementando polimorfismo, onde é necessário uma declaração de função para cada variante possível de tipagem/número de parâmetros.  (Tente imaginar o `soma3` acima podendo funcionar com combinações distintas de inteiros, números float, números decimais, fração, e cada uma dessas com 2 ou 3 parâmetros - o número de implementações necessárias cresce de forma geométrica. Ok, números podem descender de uma classe abstrata "Number" - mas dá pra pegar a ideia).

Agora sim, há ocasiões em que é mais elegante definir as funções separadamente para tipos distintos de parâmetros, do que separar internamente por `if`. Para isso,a biblioteca padrão tem um recurso de "singledispatch" que seleciona automaticamente um corpo de função dependendo do tipo do primeiro parâmetro.  No modo interativo pode se escrever:

```
In [15]: import functools

In [16]: @functools.singledispatch
    ...: def soma(a, b):
    ...:     pass
    ...: 

In [17]: @soma.register(int)
    ...: def s(a, b):
    ...:     return f"{a + b}  integer"
    ...: 

In [18]: @soma.register(str)
    ...: def s(a, b):
    ...:     return f"{a + b} string"
    ...: 



In [20]: soma(3,4)
Out[20]: '7  integer'

...
```

Note que isso está na biblioteca padrão, mas a natureza dinâmica de Python aliada a possibilidade de escrever funções de ordem mais alta - que nesse caso são usadas como decoradores, prefixando funções com a sintaxe de `@` - permite que um projeto crie seus próprios métodos para fazer um dispatch para outros métodos/funções automaticamente - e isso não é complexo quando se entende bem a linguagem.

Por fim, mas não menos importante, vale a pena mencionar que embora essas características dinâmicas de Python sejam muito legais para código de baixo acoplamento, e escrita rápida de funcionalidades, em projetos maiores, com equipes grandes, podem atrapalhar - por isso já há alguns anos Python vem evoluindo [uma especificação de anotação de tipos](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), que não *força* argumentos de um determinado tipo em tempo de execução, mas permite que ferramentas auxiliares verifiquem a tipagem usada nas chamadas em uma etapa de checagem (commit hooks, rodar testes, etc...).  Com isso se padroniza uma sintaxe introduzida no Python 3.0 que permite a especificação do tipo de um parâmetro usando-se ":" na declaração de uma função:

```
In [28]: from numbers import Number

In [29]: def soma3(a: Number, b: Number, c: Number=0):
    ...:     return a + b + c
    ...:
```

Deixa explícito para as ferramentas de checagem estática (algumas podem ser usadas de forma transparente por uma IDE, por exemplo), que a idéia é que essa função só receba tipos numéricos. Em tempo de execução no entanto, a linguagem **não** deixaria de chamar essa função se for invocada com strings, por exemplo. (Mas sim, seria possível criar uma ferramenta que desse erro automaticamente nesse caso - mas com isso: (1) tudo ficaria mais lento e (2) você perde as vantagens de estar usando uma linguagem dinâmica - você poderia usar [Cython](http://cython.org/), por exemplo que realmente pode tirar vantagens otimizando a execução ao se declarar alguns dos tipos de parâmetros)

Answer (score 12):

Python não tem. Não faz sentido em uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. A sobrecarga depende da quantidade de parâmetros e seus tipos para formar uma assinatura. O Python só tem o nome na [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), então não é possível ter este mecanismo. Mesmo com as anotações de tipos das versões mais novas, é uma camada muito superficial só para auxiliar a robustez, a tipagem continua sendo dinâmica.

A alternativa é usar um nome diferente dando uma semântica específica nele para diferenciar de outro método.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a resposta escolhida:

Realmente esta questão de sobrecarga não faz sentido considerando a tipagem dinâmica do Python. Contudo a [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading) introduz o decorador **@overload** no módulo de tipagem do Python. Este decorador funciona da seguinte maneira:

Você pode definir diversos tipos de chamadas para sua função decoradas com **@overload** e essas definições devem ser seguidas por uma definição padrão da sua função sem o decorador.

```py
from typing import overload

@overload
def process(response: None) -> None:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: int) -> tuple[int, str]:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: bytes) -> str:
    ...
def process(response):
    ...  # implementação de fato é feita aqui
```

Este tipo de implementação é útil apenas para os checadores de tipagem e torna a declaração mais explícita, mas ao ser executado, qualquer implementação realizada nas declarações com o decorador serão sobrescritas pela declaração final sem o decorador.

Para mais informações verifique a PEP citada e/ou a documentação sobre o [@typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.13/library/typing.html#typing.overload)