# Função "strcmp()" funcionando sem adicionar "string.h"

Tags: c, string, comparação, header, biblioteca

Escrevi um algoritmo em C que utiliza a função `strcmp()`. Mesmo esquecendo de adicionar o `string.h` o algoritmo funcionou.

Gostaria de entender como funcionou já que só achei essa função na biblioteca `string.h`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


typedef struct Produto{
    char nome[30];
    float preco;
}Produto;

int compara_nome(const void * A, const void* B){
Produto * pointerA=(Produto *) A;
Produto * pointerB=(Produto *) B;

return strcmp (pointerA->nome,pointerB->nome);/* como isto está funcionando sem o string.h ?*/


}
int compara_preco(const void * A, const void * B){
    Produto * pointerA=(Produto *) A;
    Produto * pointerB=(Produto *) B;
return (pointerA->preco-pointerB->preco);

}


int main(){
 static Produto Estoque[10]={{"Leite",5.50},{"Donuts",23.6},{"Detergente",4.15},{"Acucar",7.84},
 {"Brigadeiro",12.30},{"Limão",3.48},{"Morango",6.21},{"Tomate",4.12},{"Feijao",3.10},{"Skol",7.89}};

 qsort(Estoque,10,sizeof(Produto),compara_nome);

 int i;
 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("Nome: %-10s\t  Preco:%5.2f \t\n",Estoque[i].nome,Estoque[i].preco);
 }
qsort(Estoque,10,sizeof(Produto),compara_preco);    
printf("-----------------------------------------------");
printf("\n");
 for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("Nome: %-10s\t  Preco:%5.2f \t\n",Estoque[i].nome,Estoque[i].preco);
 }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que está no arquivo de cabeçalho é apenas a [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) da função, não a sua implementação. Se a implementação está disponível, na *linkedição* funcionará. Nesse caso o compilador reconhece ser possível chamá-la sem maiores verificações e confia que dará certo. O ideal é não fazer assim porque se chamar de forma equivocada dará erro em tempo de execução, um erro que poderia ser detectado na compilação se tivesse a assinatura avaliada.

C tem muitas coisas que funcionam mas não é garantido que esteja certo. Lembre-se que C é um Assembly portável e não uma linguagem de alto nível com todas verificações possíveis. Por isso sempre digo:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Especialmente em C as pessoas precisam se acostumam com a filosofia de entender o que está fazendo e acontecendo e não confiar no resultado. Em C moderno isso é considerado um erro. É possível ligar uma análise no compilador para não deixar acontecer, aconselho fazê-lo, caso contrário lidará com algo como "funciona na minha máquina" que sempre é um problema do programador.

[Assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) é só um contrato a ser seguido, não é algo que executa um código. A execução será inserida normalmente e torce-se para que funcione.

Comment: Interessante!! Tinha a ideia que o compilador ou o linkeditor só adicionava funções citadas nos protótipos(ou assinatura?) dos cabeçalhos. Pelo visto não é o caso. Quando você fala de " C modernos"  está falando de ISO's?  
Já li algumas coisas sobre elas, mas não sei se devo focar nelas agora no início. Desculpe o desconhecimento dos termos da área.

Comment: Cada um faz o que acha melhor pra si, e tem gente que prefere ficar no jeito antigo porque supostamente é mais portável (mesmo isso se não usar assinaturas fica menos portável), eu prefiro trabalhar sempre com C99 pelo menos ou C18 onde dá. Os compiladores que não aceitam, essas novidades geralmente são plataformas que você tem que fazer código diferente de qualquer jeito.