# Quero entender como funciona a variável de instância e a variável local dos parâmetros

Tags: java, variáveis, método, parâmetros, declaração-de-variável

```
 public Exemplo {

        private int name;

        public Exemplo(int name)
        {
           this.name = name;
        }

        public void setName(int name)
        {
           this.name = name;
        }


    public int getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

}
```

Quero entender como a variável `private int name;` e a variável local dos parâmentos funciona.

Pelo que eu entendi, quando a variável dentro do parâmetro tem o mesmo nome que a variável de instancia, o corpo desse método irá referenciar a variável local em vez da variável de instancia. "A variável local simula a variável de instancia no corpo do método"

A minha dúvida é: o valor que será implementado no método `setName`, com a utilização do argumento `this.name = name;` ele será alocado na variável de instancia ou será atribuído somente ao método `getName`? para onde esses valores seguem, para a instancia ou para o construtor?

E além disso, se por exemplo, eu tivesse um contador como variável de instancia:

```
private int contador = 0;
```

E tivesse um método para dar um `contador++`, esse método teria que, obrigatoriamente ser referenciado no construtor?

Tipo, eu criar um objeto e um `objetoTest` e, neste ultimo, ter um laço de repetição que retorna a quantidade de pessoas com cabelo Branco. Como eu faria? eu não consegui entender.

Comment: bem vindo ao SOpt, eu formatei sua pergunta e editei o primeiro paragrafo pq estava um pouco confuso, verifica se eu entendi correto, se não você pode recusar a edição. =D

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Os termos estão mal usados na pergunta.

Existe a variável de instância, a variável de classe, e a variável local, além do parâmetro que na verdade é uma variável local que é inicializada por sua chamada.

Nunca ouvi o termo cabeçalho de método, no máximo [assinatura de método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101), mas entendi o que quer dizer.

Não existe variável dentro do parâmetro, existe variável que é [parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Quando há colisão de nomes a variável local sempre tem prioridade, o `this` costuma ser usado para desambiguar.

> "A variável local simula a variável de instancia no corpo do método"

Não. Quando não há colisão a variável de instância pode ser acessada de forma direta da mesma forma que a variável local, mas é só uma facilidade de sintaxe, a semântica não é de variável local.

Valores não são implementados. Não estamos falando de alocação aí, nem é nada atribuído a métodos.

`this.name = name;` está pegando o valor da variável local `name`, que por acaso é um parâmetro, e está atribuindo à variável de instância `name`, só isso e nada mais.

A segunda parte da pergunta parece ter nada a ver com a primeira parte, mas vamos lá.

Você usa no construtor o que precisa construir, o que não precisa não usa. Veja mais em [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Mas métodos de instância não devem ser referenciados no construtor, porque até terminar a construção eles não inválidos.

Eu começaria por tentar entender as coisas como elas realmente são, dar nomes corretos para as coisas. O fato de isso ainda estar confuso vai prejudicar o aprendizado. A parte final da pergunta está extremante confusa e provavelmente nem faz parte do escopo deste site responder isso, fora que nem parece fazer parte do resto da pergunta. Sem o entendimento mais básico eu nem tentaria insistir isso.

A pergunta parte de outras premissas potencialmente erradas, mas nem vou entrar neste mérito que é algo mais avançado.

Answer (score 0):

> A minha dúvida é, o valor que será implementado no método setName, com a utilização do argumento "this.name = name;" ele será alocado na variável de instancia ou será atribuído somente ao método getName? para onde esses valores seguem, para a instancia ou para o construtor?

this.name refere-se a variável de instância, note que no setName você está atribuindo um valor a variável de instância.

Os métodos setAlgumaCoisa servem para que você possa atribuir um valor a sua variável de instância, para preencher os valores do objeto antes de, por exemplo, salvá-lo no banco de dados.

Os métodos getAlgumaCoisa servem para recuperar um valor de instância para fazer algo com ele, por exemplo, exibir na tela.

> E, alem disso, se, Por exemplo, eu tivesse um contador como variável de instancia:
>
> private int contador = 0;
>
> E tivesse um método para dar um contador++, esse método teria que, obrigatoriamente ser referenciado no construtor?

Esse método não precisa ser obrigatóriamente referenciado no construtor, você pode instanciar seu objeto e depois chamar o método, assim:

```
MeuObjeto meuObjeto = new MeuObjeto();
meuObjeto.contador();
```

> Pelo que eu entendi, quando a variável dentro do parâmetro tem o mesmo nome que a variável de instancia, o corpo desse método irá referenciar a variável local em vez da variável de instancia. "A variável local simula a variável de instancia no corpo do método"

Na verdade não ocorre uma simulação aqui, o this é usado apenas para fazer distinção entre a variável de instancia e a variavel de parâmetro do método, quando a há repetição de nome, caso contrario o uso do this não é obrigatório.