# Classe que implementa duas interfaces que possuem métodos de assinaturas idênticas

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Possuo uma classe que implementa duas interfaces. Cada uma dessas interfaces possui um método idêntico, por exemplo:

```
    public interface InterfaceA{
       void doSomething(String params);
    }



    public interface InterfaceB{
       void doSomething(String params);
    }
```

Ambas possuem um método `doSomething(String params)` com o mesmo nome e assinatura. Sabemos que toda classe que implementa uma interface deve obrigatoriamente pelo contrato, implementar seus métodos ou tornar-se abstrata. Sendo assim, se eu tiver uma classe que implemente as duas interfaces, o compilador invocará o método de qual interface quando o método da `ClasseQualquer` for chamado? A `ClasseQualquer` implementa o método de qual interface? Como os métodos em suas assinaturas são idênticos não faz diferença nenhuma?

```
public void ClasseQualquer implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
   @Override   
   public void doSomething(String params){

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua observação sobre contratos está correta, você tem apenas um contrato, mas então não está correto que haverá invocação do método de uma das interfaces, não existe método nelas, tem só contratos de métodos (até tem isto a partir de Java 8, mas não é um caso que a pergunta quer saber). A invocação será o método que está na classe, só isso.

A invocação poderá ocorrer em qualquer objeto que seja do tipo de classe, de tipos descendentes dela (embora poderá ser um método descendente e não exatamente desta classe) ou poderá ocorrer quando estiver usando uma das duas interfaces, que chamará o método da classe com a mesma [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

Como Java não tem implementação explícita de método de interface não tem como diferenciar uma ou outra, portanto se invocar pela `InterfaceA` ou pela `InterfaceB` chamará o mesmo método. Tem linguagem, como C# por exemplo, que permite que cada uma tenha sua própria implementação afinal o mais provável é que você tenha objetivos bem diferentes entre elas apesar do método ter coincidentemente a mesma assinatura. Quase sempre se tiver duas interfaces com um método com a mesma assinatura e que eles devam fazer a mesma coisa é erro de *design* e Java não tem como lidar de forma adequada os casos corretos onde tem a mesma assinatura mas objetivos diferentes.

Então se faz diferença ou não, depende do que está fazendo. Se o *design* é ruim não faz diferença, se de fato cada método tem objetivo diferente você terá que tratar isso dentro da implementação do método tornando o código menos robusto e mais lento.

Por que você faria duas interfaces com a mesma assinatura e objetivo? Ou é um caso hipotético que não ocorre ou é algo mal pensado (alguns casos que fogem do seu controle). Mesmo os casos que os objetivos são diferentes dá pra pensar se houve uma boa escolha ali, pode fazer sentido em alguns casos, mas se acontecer muito também é algo mal arquitetado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Opa, era só um caso hipotético mesmo. Uma dúvida que me surgiu. Faz todo sentido a sua resposta e conseguiu sanar a minha dúvida. Vou marcar sua resposta como a resposta correta para esse post. Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Quando você diz que sua classe `ClasseQualquer` implementa uma interface, isso é apenas um contrato que existe durante o tempo de compilação.

Veja por outro lado: implementações implícitas. Em algumas linguagens, você não precisa declarar que classe X implementa interface Y, você apenas declara a interface Y, e se a classe X implementar todos o métodos declarados na interface, então esta classe X está automaticamente implementando a interface Y.

Java possui implementações explicitas, você tem que indicar que sua classe de fato está implementando a interface, mas isso é apenas para garantir que você não estará implementando algo por acidente.

No fim, o importante é que a sua classe possua os métodos e atributos dessa interface. Se uma função quer um parâmetro do tipo `InterfaceA`, isso só significa que ela quer um objeto com o método `public void doSomething(String)`. O fato de você ter que declarar a sua classe implementando a interface não altera o comportamento do código compilado, isso é apenas uma garantia que o compilador exige.

Comment: Sensacional amigo. Complementou ainda mais a resposta do usuário @Maniero e me forneceu ainda mais informações sobre como funciona a implementação de interfaces no Java. Muito obrigado!!!