# O que significa a sintaxe " bool operator < " em C++?

Tags: c++, operadores

Eu procurei essa referência (`bool operator <` e  `bool operator ==`), encontrei algumas explicações, mas não entendi muito bem. Como funciona essa sintaxe?

Código:

```
bool operator < (nome a, nome b){
   return a.idade < b.idade;
}

bool operator == (nome a, nome b){
   return a.idade == b.idade;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Isso é a declaração de um operador. C++ permite [sobrecarga de operador](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). Então você pode escrever o código com o comportamento do operador para certos tipos. No fundo você está criando uma função que será executada quando encontrar esse operador sendo com esse tipo. Claro que a função não precisa ser necessariamente chamada já que o código costuma ser muito simples e provavelmente haverá uma otimização que colocará o código dela diretamente onde foi usado (*inline optimization*).

Isso faz parte da [assinatura da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Obviamente precisa da palavra chave `operator` para diferenciar de uma função normal e o compilador não se confundir com a sintaxe e ajuda ficar mais legível.

Nesse exemplo está demonstrando como compara dois objetos do tipo `nome` e que deve ser pego a idade de cada objeto para comparar e dizer se é menor ou então igual no outro. Provavelmente é um código meio sem sentido, então entenda o mecanismo mas não faça como viu isso em algum lugar.