# Devo usar String ou Map?

Tags: java, string, map

Bom preciso criar um método que recebe três strings: cor, marca e modelo.

Seria melhor colocar um map que receberia por exemplo ("color", "blue") ou receber direto o "blue" como string?
Pergunto isso pq não sei se seria uma prática ruim, nesse caso, lançar direto a string, ja que se um outro desenvolvedor for usar meu método, terá que saber a ordem exata de cada atributo.

```
public class getPhone(String color, String brand, String model){
return (SELECT Id, Name, Hierarchy FROM Products WHERE Color = color, Brand = brand, Model = model);}
```

Ou

```
public class getPhone(Map<String, String> color, Map<String,String> brand, Map<String, String> model){

String colorInput =(String)color.get('Color');
String brandInput =(String)brand.get('Brand');
String modelInput =(String)model.get('Model');

return (SELECT Id, Name, Hierarchy FROM Products WHERE Color = colorInput, Brand = brandInput, Model = modelInput);}
```

Comment: O fato de usar `String` ou `Map` não elimina a necessidade de saber a ordem correta dos argumentos. Até porque todos seriam exatamente do mesmo tipo (ou todos são `String`, ou todos são `Map<String, String>`, então se eu trocasse a ordem deles, o código compilaria do mesmo jeito e eu só perceberia depois que a ordem está errada). Mudar o tipo não resolve nada, e usar o tipo inadequado pode até complicar mais. Aliás, usar `Map` me parece uma complicação desnecessária, vá de string mesmo...

Comment: _se um outro desenvolvedor for usar meu método, terá que saber a ordem exata de cada atributo_ - Isso vale para qualquer método de qualquer classe que você está usando (não só para as que você criou, mas também para API's nativas, ou libs de terceiros, etc). E para isso existe a documentação. No caso do Java, existe uma sintaxe específica: comentários que começam com `/**` (chamados de [Javadoc](https://www.oracle.com/br/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html)) - coloque comentários explicando que cada parâmetro é, assim todos saberão como usar o método

Comment: Se tiver um conjunto de valores pre-definidos (por exemplo, somente "blue", "yellow", etc), talvez seja melhor criar uma classe específica para a cor (que por sua vez sabe quais são as cores válidas), ou então um `enum` (sem saber dos requisitos, não dá pra cravar qual é o mais apropriado para o seu caso). O mesmo vale para `brand` e `model` (se puder ter "qualquer coisa", aí talvez seja melhor deixar como string mesmo). Mas não vejo motivo nenhum para trocar para `Map`

Comment: Pessoal, isso é sintaxe nova do Java? Para mim esse `return (SELECT ...);` nem compilaria. E ataque de injeção de SQL também creio que está mandando um abraço, convém se informar sobre `PreparedStatement`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que temos duas alternativas boas aqui:

1. Utilizar os parâmetros como `String`

   ```
   public class getPhone(String color, String brand, String model)
   ```

   Sobre a sua preocupação sobre o desenvolvedor saber a ordem dos parâmetros para utilização do método, é exatamente para isso que a [assinatura do método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39870/o-que-%C3%A9-a-assinatura-de-um-m%C3%A9todo) serve.

   Do ponto de vista de utilização, saber quais argumentos devem ser passados é muito melhor do que a utilização do `Map`, conforme vou explicar mais abaixo.

   Essa alternativa não é boa se você tiver de considerar muitos parâmetros para o filtro, deixando a assinatura do método muito grande.
2. Passar um objeto para realizar o filtro:

   ```
   public class getPhone(PhoneFilter filter)
   ```

   Essa alternativa vem mais com o intuito de evitar aumentar a assinatura do método no futuro, com o objetivo de reaproveitar o objeto para novos filtros e também padronizar a construção do objeto com filtros obrigatórios/opcionais, e mais algumas vantagens.

Eu não utilizaria o `Map` por conta de:

1. O desenvolvedor que irá utilizar seu método não saberá prontamente ao olhar o método qual parâmetro deve incluir no mapa, da mesma forma como ele pode incluir propriedades que não são esperadas e não serão utilizadas:

```
productInfo.put("propriedadeAleatoria") // Se for colocada essa propriedade em algum outro nível da aplicação, não será utilizada na query
...
productInfo.get("color") // Se o color não for populado, será retornado null para a filtragem da query
```

2. Apesar de ser tentador do ponto de vista de flexibilidade, quando um novo parâmetro for adicionado à query, seria apenas incluir no mapa, ainda temos o problema do primeiro item, sobre visibilidade.

Para resolver o problema da visibilidade dessa abordage, eu utilizaria a alternativa 2, mas apenas se o número de opções de filtragem aumentasse de forma considerável, senão, utilizaria a alternativa 1 mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar JavaDoc para especificar a ordem em que os parâmetros devem ser fornecidos.

Você pode saber mais aqui:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html

Se quiser usar map você pode fazer desta forma:

```
public Map<String, String> productInfo = new HashMap<>();
this.productInfo.put("color", "blue");
this.productInfo.put("brand", "brand");
this.productInfo.put("model", "model");

public class getPhone(Map<String, String> productInfo){
  String colorInput = productInfo.get("color");
  String brandInput = productInfo.get("brand");
  String modelInput = productInfo.get("model");

  return (SELECT Id, Name, Hierarchy FROM Products WHERE Color = colorInput, Brand = brandInput, Model = modelInput);
}
```

Acho que talvez usar o JavaDoc é a melhor opção, até porque de qualquer forma o desenvolvedor que for usar se código terá que saber quais informações irão no Map, mas vai de você como desenvolvedor pensar na melhor solução, abraços.