# Como entender o parâmetro de posição no array usando IndexOf()?

Tags: c#, .net, string, indexof

Realizando algumas pesquisas no comportamento do método `IndexOf()` em C# notei sobre o comportamento do "5" onde começa a contagem na posição declarada no *array*. Porém não entendi como se comporta essa posição.

````cs
 String myStr = "Olá planeta terra, você é um grande planeta";
            Console.WriteLine(myStr.IndexOf("e", 5)); //8```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [`IndexOf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do tipo `String` tem algumas [assinaturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) e cada um pode ter um comportamento diferente.

Na [sobrecarga específica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32)&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) usada, o método procura por um texto dentro de outro texto, começando na posição indicada. Ou seja, os caracteres anteriores a esta posição são ignorado na busca pelo texto a ser achado, portanto ele ignora o `Olá p` e começa olha só no `laneta terra, você é um grande planeta`.

Se ele achar o que está procurando ele retorna a posição onde esse texto está dentro do outro texto. Ele acha a posição do texto inteiro, ele não ignora a posição dos caracteres não olhados. No caso do exemplo ignorar os 5 primeiros caracteres não muda o resultado porque não tem nada que está sendo procurado a excluir.

Se tivesse usado para começar na posição 9 então o resultado seria outro, já que ele ignoraria o primeiro `e` e acharia o segundo na posição 13.

Só para completeza, se ele não achar o que está procurando o resultado será -1 (posição inválida). E se ele achar o texto uma vez ele não continua procurando pro outras ocorrências. E este método procura da esquerda para a direita, tem [outro método que faz a busca do lado oposto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Então o texto não deixa de ser um *array*, e cada caractere está em uma posição desse *array*. Começa da posição 0 e vai até o tamanho do texto - 1, já que começando do zero tem que tirar esse 1. Pode ser que ache estranho isso e que deveria retornar 9, mas isso é igual ao *array*. Tamanho do texto é 43, então as posições que existem é de 0 até 42 (se tiver dúvida, conte e verá que tem 43):

```
          1         2         3         4
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012
Olá planeta terra, você é um grande planeta
```

Talvez ajude vizualizar com um código que é uma simplificação de como seria o `IndexOf()`:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(IndexOf("Olá planeta terra, você é um grande planeta", 'e', 9));

int IndexOf(string haystack, char needle, int offset) {
    for (int i = offset; i < haystack.Length; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PLpE5y). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hlxUyN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/IndexOf.cs).

[Código real](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Searching.cs,458eb43a8be97cd7) (tem que ir clicando nos métodos chamados para chegar na real implementação).

Comment: Maneiro eu ainda não entendi sobre a pesquisa "5", como ele se comporta dentro do parâmetro?

Comment: @CristianSouza parece que a assinatura que vc usou na pergunta é [essa](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32)). Nesse caso, ele vai procurar o primeiro `"e"` a partir do índice `8`, ou seja, ele irá procurar sua string a partir da posição 8. Se você colocar `9` ele irá retornar `13`, pois o próximo `"e"` após `8` está em `13`.

Comment: @CristianSouza https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMTOni

Comment: @CristianSouza então está difícil entender o que quer saber. Na verdade essa frase nem faz sentido. Se você conseguir explicar o que quer dizer isso sem repetir o que já foi dito na pergunta talvez dê para explicar melhor.

Comment: @Maniero desculpa a falta de coesão, então vamos la, deixa eu ver se da pra explica melhor. na sentença que eu mencionei na pergunta está assim Console.WriteLine(myStr.IndexOf("e", 5)). esse 5 que passei depois do "e". Qual o significado dele nessa aplicação?

Comment: Não está na resposta?

Comment: @Maniero ok verifiquei aqui, agora entendi!

Answer (score 1):

O array começa no índice 0.

É possível ver isso através deste trecho de código:

```
var myStr = "Ola planeta terra, voçe é um grande planeta";
var arr = myStr.ToCharArray();
for(var x =0; x < arr.Length ; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Posição: {0} | Valor: {1}", x, arr[x]);
}
```

O resultado é este:

```
Posição:  0 | Valor: O
Posição:  1 | Valor: l
Posição:  2 | Valor: a
Posição:  3 | Valor:  
Posição:  4 | Valor: p
Posição:  5 | Valor: l
Posição:  6 | Valor: a
Posição:  7 | Valor: n
Posição:  8 | Valor: e
Posição:  9 | Valor: t
Posição: 10 | Valor: a
Posição: 11 | Valor:  
Posição: 12 | Valor: t
Posição: 13 | Valor: e
Posição: 14 | Valor: r
Posição: 15 | Valor: r
Posição: 16 | Valor: a
Posição: 17 | Valor: ,
Posição: 18 | Valor:  
Posição: 19 | Valor: v
Posição: 20 | Valor: o
Posição: 21 | Valor: ç
Posição: 22 | Valor: e
Posição: 23 | Valor:  
Posição: 24 | Valor: é
Posição: 25 | Valor:  
Posição: 26 | Valor: u
Posição: 27 | Valor: m
Posição: 28 | Valor:  
Posição: 29 | Valor: g
Posição: 30 | Valor: r
Posição: 31 | Valor: a
Posição: 32 | Valor: n
Posição: 33 | Valor: d
Posição: 34 | Valor: e
Posição: 35 | Valor:  
Posição: 36 | Valor: p
Posição: 37 | Valor: l
Posição: 38 | Valor: a
Posição: 39 | Valor: n
Posição: 40 | Valor: e
Posição: 41 | Valor: t
Posição: 42 | Valor: a
```

Logo a primeira letra 'E' está na posição 8.

Comment: Contudo com a posição inicial de pesquisa esse "5", qual a função dele no array?