# Que tipo de tratamento pode ser realizado nesse caso?

Tags: java, exceção

No momento quero aprender mais sobre tratamento de exceções, tópico que é muito bem comentado pelo @Maniero. Li várias respostas dele sobre exceções, mas ainda fiquei com uma dúvida.

O método `prepareStatement()` assim como os métodos `setString()`, `setInt()`, etc, exigem o tratamento de uma `SQLException`.

Depois da leitura de vários artigos entendi que manipular uma exceção e tratá-la são suas coisas diferentes.

Ao meu ver, o código abaixo está apenas manipulando a exceção mas não a trata.

```
public void update(Pessoa pessoa) {

    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conexao.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, pessoa.getCpf());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, pessoa.getIdPessoa());
        preparedStatement.execute();
        preparedStatement.close();
        conexao.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

1. Gostaria de ver um exemplo de um tratamento adequado para essa exceção nesse caso.
2. Ao manipular essa checked exception, guardando o `StrackTrace` em um *log* e mostrando um aviso ao usuário que algo de que não foi possível realizar o *update* dos dados, seria considerado que a exceção foi tratada?
3. E se ao tópico acima fosse acrescentado que fossem limpos os campos de preenchimento dos dados pessoais e voltasse a tela inicial de alteração de dados para que o usuário tente fazer a edição novamente, seria considerado que a exceção foi tratada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Na verdade a forma de tratar depende da necessidade da aplicação. Os requisitos da aplicação é que determinarão o que você deve fazer. A pergunta que você deve fazer é o que deve acontecer com a aplicação caso tenha um determinado problema.

   Uma observação importante é que você está só capturando exceção de SQL. Nenhum problema nisto, pode ser o certo a fazer. Mas já se perguntou se existem outras exceções que devem ser tratadas aí também? Só estou dizendo isto para reflexão, não estou dizendo que está errado. Só você sabe o que a a aplicação precisa fazer.
2. Sim, a exceção foi tratada aí. Ela não resolveu o problema mas foi tratada. Se você faz alguma coisa útil, faz algo que está previsto na aplicação, há um tratamento. *Logar* e avisar o usuário normalmente é uma dos tratamentos mais comuns, ainda mais em erros de SQL.

   No código apresentado não está fazendo nenhuma das duas coisas de forma clara, mas acredito que é só porque é um exemplo. Mesmo assim não deixa de estar apresentando um erro para o usuário, só não está de uma forma bonita. Não sei se a aplicação pode continuar executando em estado confiável depois disto. Na forma atual o método `update` não tem nenhum mecanismo que indique que houve um erro de SQL. Nem deixou a exceção transbordar para outro método tratar nem informa de alguma forma que houve o erro. Sem ver o resto do código alguma coisa me diz que algo errado acontecerá em consequência disso.
3. Este procedimento descrito é uma forma de tratar a exceção e resolver o problema. Não sei se deveria limpar os dados (foram eles que causaram o problema e precisam ser digitados de novo?).

   Mas tem um problema aí. Este método apenas deveria fazer uma atualização. Este método não deveria se envolver com a interface com o usuário. O erro provável aí é que está tratando uma exceção onde não deveria. Digo provável porque não conheço a aplicação como um todo.

   Se o tratamento é mexer com a interface é **provável** que outro método é que deveria tratar esta exceção. Nas minhas respostas eu digo sempre: não trate o que você não sabe ou não consegue tratar naquele momento. No no método de atualização você não consegue tratar da interface (tecnicamente é possível, mas pode desorganizar toda a aplicação, vai ferir o princípio da [responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/101)).

## Uma possível solução

Como a exceção é checada a aplicação é obrigada dar algum tratamento, seja ele qual for, não precisa resolver o problema. Quer saber como resolver isto neste método? Não faça nada nele, delegue para outro método resolver o problema. Informe ao compilador que quem chamar o método `update()` deve se virar. Se este método for parte da interface com usuário, ele será o local certo para tratar a exceção. Se não for, deve delegar novamente para outro método.

E como delegar para outro método sem ferir a exceção checada? Simples, não capture ela aí e crie uma assinatura no método obrigando que outro método trate a exceção:

```
public void update(Pessoa pessoa) throws SQLException { //note o throws aqui
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conexao.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, pessoa.getCpf());
    preparedStatement.setInt(3, pessoa.getIdPessoa());
    preparedStatement.execute();
    preparedStatement.close();
    conexao.close();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Example.java).

Note que esta é um solução baseado no que você está dizendo na pergunta. Pode ser que a solução correta seja capturar aí dentro do método mesmo. Só duvido que seja. Não é comum ser.

É, eu sei, eu apenas disse que aí não é o lugar correto e não dei a solução. Eu vou ficar devendo uma exemplo mais completo porque eu não costumo programar em Java, ainda mais com banco de dados e interface com usuário.

Se isso não sanou sua dúvida, espero que tenha outra resposta mais na mosca.

Comment: você esclareceu uma dúvida que eu tinha com relação ao throws, muito obrigada! Agora ficou muito claro quem deveria utilizar o throws, quem deve usar o try-catch e como isso ajuda na divisão de responsabilidades, mas gostaria de confirmar mais uma vez então: simplesmente fazer o log e mostrar uma mensagem de erro ao usuário é considerado tratar? Porque em um caso onde o usuário tentou fazer um cadastro/edição/etc e deu erro, não teria motivo para encerrar a aplicação já que apenas uma operação não deu certo, o programa não precisa quebrar todo por isso (com a consistência dos dados)...

Comment: Nesse tipo de caso, apresentar a mensagem e logar é considerado a atitude correta? Um caso de tratamento diferente de simplesmente logar o erro e apresentar ao usuário seria por exemplo uma conexão mal sucedida, que dentro do catch eu tentaria conectar novamente? Eu não tenho experiência em programação e nunca vi um código que fizesse dentro do catch algo além de logar, apresentar mensagem de erro e lançar a exceção, gostaria de ver um código **em qualquer linguagem** que fizesse algo além do café com leite.

Comment: Sim, é considerado. Não quer dizer que resolveu o problema. Mas o tratamento de exceção não precisa obrigatoriamente resolver o problemas. É apenas desejável que o faça. Se você não consegue resolver o problema o que dá para fazer é informar que houve um problema e **se** o usuário pode resolver pedir para ele mudar algo (possivelmente pedindo para ele mudar alguma informação digitada) é adequado. Isto é um tratamento. E bem comum. De fato quebrar a aplicação quando o usuário pode resolver não faz sentido. Em geral só deve deixar a aplicação quebrar quando é erro de programação ou falha geral.

Comment: Quando você usa o `throws` (não confundir com `throw`) é tratar. Está tratando de dizer que a exceção deve ser melhor tratada em outro lugar. No exemplo da conexão é isto mesmo que poderia ser feito. Mas também poderia perguntar ao usuário o que ele deseja fazer? Algo como (simplificadamente, você teria que explicar melhor as possibilidades) "deu um erro, verifique se a rede está ok. Quer tentar novamente?" e ele decide quando tentar novamente depois de arrumar o problema. Pode fazer um misto de tentar x vezes em intervalo de tempo e depois perguntar.

Comment: De fato os exemplos costumam ser fracos. É raro  ver um exemplo real do que é adequado fazer. Mas na maioria das vezes se o erro pode ser resolvido, tem que pedir para o usuário fazer algo. É raro a própria aplicação conseguir resolver sozinha um problema. Quase sempre quando isto ocorre provavelmente não deveria estar usando uma exceção e sim um controle de fluxo normal informando um problema de outra forma. Em alguns raros casos você pode mandar a aplicação tentar um outro caminho, alga ação que só deve ser usada como reserva.

Comment: Perfeito, tem algum post que trate sobre essa questão de quando usar o controle de fluxo e quando usar a exceção? Eu sei que você sempre fala essa mesma frase mas não vejo muitos exemplos, exceto aquela resposta sobre o parse e o tryParse que achei muito interessante, valia a pena ter um tópico com mais exemplos desse tipo: códigos que deveriam usar controle de fluxo ao contrário de exceção.

Comment: Talvez falte exemplos práticos mesmo, verei o que posso fazer. Talvez você já tenha visto mas tem alguns lugares que escrevi que ajudam um pouco a entender em termos gerais. Para conferir se viu tudo : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o ou só http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o (não garanto a confiabilidade do que postado por terceiros :P ) Aqui fala que o único tipo de exceção boa de lidar são as estrangerias: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101. Aqui falo do `throws`: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17028/101

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Gostaria de ver um exemplo de um tratamento adequado para essa exceção nesse caso.

Depende muito do tipo de sistema.

Se for desktop, você pode mostrar uma caixa de diálogo com a mensagem de erro. Se for web, você pode devolver a página para o usuário com a mensagem de erro em alguma parte do HTML.

O importante ao tratar uma exceção é que o comportamento do sistema seja coerente, que ele não caia num erro pior ainda e não esconda os erros do usuário.

Como exibir mensagens de erro não deve ser a responsabilidade das classes de acesso a banco de dados (*Data Access Objects*, por exemplo), então uma forma de realizar um tratamento adequado é encapsular as exceções do banco em uma exceção genérica de banco de dados e tratar esta outra exceção em classes de controle (*Controllers*).

Por exemplo:

```java
public void update(Pessoa pessoa) throws DataBaseException {
    Connection conexao = getConexao();
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conexao.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, pessoa.getCpf());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, pessoa.getIdPessoa());
        preparedStatement.execute();
        preparedStatement.close();
        conexao.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e); 
        throw new DataBaseException("Erro ao atualizar a pessoa!", e);
    } finally {
        if (conexao != null) {
            try {
               conexao.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e); 
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

O método acima salva o erro original num arquivo de *log* usando uma API próprio, pois "printar" erros para a saída não é uma boa prática.

Além disso, ele encapsula qualquer exceção numa exceção customizada `DataBaseException`. Esta exceção seria usada em todas as rotinas de acesso a banco de dados.

Outro detalhe é que é necessário um bloco `finally` para fechar a conexão, caso contrário um erro resultaria em vazamento de conexões, isto é, vários conexões abertas e não fechadas. Isso é uma grande dor de cabeça em sistemas mal planejados. O servidor começa a travar após algum tempo de uso e vai demorar até alguém descobrir o problema.

O segundo `catch` não precisa de tratamento além do log, pois ele só tenta fechar a conexão. Se isso falhar o problema é maios embaixo e não há muito o que fazer.

Em geral, é "feio" capturar uma exceção genérica como `Exception`. Mas há um motivo para isso. Existem casos, como o desenvolvedor colocar um parâmetro a mais no `PreparedStatement`, onde ocorreria um erro diferente de `SQLException`. E há uma regra do mundo dos negócios: *não mostre o erro técnico para o usuário*.

Deixar escapar um erro como `NullPointerException` ou `StringIndexOutOfBroundsException` para a tela é pior do que mostrar um erro genérico. A mensagem "ocorreu um erro inesperado, entre em contato com o suporte" é às vezes o que há de mais útil para o usuário que não conhece nada sobre tecnologia.

Os casos de erro em que realmente o usuário pode atuar podem ser tratados especificamente. Por exemplo, caso o usuário tente excluir um registro que é chave estrangeira de outra tabela, então é possível mostrar uma mensagem específica de que é necessário excluir os dados da outra tabela antes de excluir o registro atual.

Dá pra fazer um mecanismo mais sofisticado do que apenas colocar `catch` com `Exception`, mas vou deixar assim nesta resposta para efeito de exemplo. Esse mecanismo poderia consistir numa rotina de tratamento global que mostrasse para o usuário mensagens diferentes para cada tipo de exceção.

Vamos imaginar agora um método que trata a ação do usuário para atualizar os dados da `Pessoa`.

Se fosse um sistema desktop:

```java
public void doCliqueBotarAtualizarAction() {
    Pessoa pessoa = recuperarPessoaDosCamposDaTela();
    try {
        pessoaDAO.update(pessoa);
        mostrarDialogoSucesso("Dados alterados com sucesso!");
    } catch (DataBaseException e) {
        mostrarDialogoErro(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O método acima simplesmente mostra uma caixa de sucesso ou fracasso dependendo do caso.

Se fosse um sistema web com Spring MVC, por exemplo:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/atualizaPessoa", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView atualizarPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
    try {
        pessoaDAO.update(pessoa);
        return new ModelAndView("tela-pesquisa")
            .addObject("mensagem", "Dados alterados com sucesso!");
    } catch (DataBaseException e) {
        return new ModelAndView("tela-edicao")
            .addObject("pessoa", pessoa)
            .addObject("mensagemErro", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O método acima recebe uma requisição `POST` para atualizar a pessoa. Se ocorrer sucesso o usuário é direcionado para a tela de pesquisa com a mensagem de sucesso. Se ocorrer falha, o usuário é direcionado para a tela de edição mostrando a pessoa e também a mensagem de erro.

Outra abordagem seria tratar separadamente `SQLException` de outro tipo de `Exception`, porém deve-se analisar se na prática vai dar alguma diferença, pois replicar o tratamento de erro para fazer a mesma coisa simplesmente não faria sentido.

> 2. Ao manipular essa checked exception, guardando o StrackTrace em um Log e mostrando um aviso ao usuário que algo de que não foi possível realizar o Update dos dados, seria considerado que a exceção foi tratada?

Sim, desde que garante que o sistema não vai ficar num estado inconsistente.

Mostrar a mensagem é suficiente se não houver efeitos colaterais indesejados.

Para casos, por exemplo, houve são alteradas várias tabelas, é importante colocar as alterações numa transação e fazer o *rollback* em caso de falha.

Veja um exemplo:

```java
public void transferencia(Conta fonte, Conta destino, BigDecimal valor) throws BusinessException {
    boolean sucesso = false;
    iniciarTransacao();
    try {
        contaDao.debitar(fonte, valor);
        contaDao.creditar(destino, valor);
        sucesso = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        throw new BusinessException("Não foi possível efetuar a transferência!", e);
    } finally {
        if (sucesso) efetuarTransacao();
        else desfazerTransacao();
    }
}
```

> 3. E se ao tópico acima fosse acrescentado que fossem limpos os campos de preenchimento dos dados pessoais e voltasse a tela inicial de alteração de dados para que o usuário tente fazer a edição novamente, seria considerado que a exceção foi tratada?

Limpar os dados geralmente não é uma boa ideia, afinal é trabalho a mais e dor de cabeça para o usuário.

Mostrar os campos com problema é uma tarefa melhor se for o caso. Para isso é importante validar os campos **antes** de tentar executar a consulta no banco de dados.

Em geral, as *constraints* do banco de dados como *unique* ou *not null* devem ser usadas para garantir a integridade do banco, mas para validação de entrada do usuário elas devem ser o último recurso.

E se o erro for de SQL, como uma sintaxe incorreta, não vai adiantar o usuário tentar de novo, provavelmente é um bug do sistema.

## Considerações

O nível de detalhe do tratamento de erros varia muito de caso para caso.

O melhor é codificar de forma "segura" validando bem todas as entradas, criando testes unitários para validar suas consultas e, assim, minimizar qualquer possibilidade de um erro no SQL.

Comment: Não devia colocar wiki. Tem algum motivo especial p/ isto? Eu tenho só uma crítica a estes códigos. Não que esteja errado, até faz algum sentido. Eles capturarem qualquer exceção e lançar outra mais específica não me agrada. Digo que faz sentido porque a nova exceção diz que não foi possível realizar a operação em especificar o que ocorreu ou como ajudar a resolver. E é verdade, mas não ajuda em nada.

Comment: Talvez ele colocou como wiki sem perceber? Tb nao entendi o pq de ser wiki

Comment: @Math é, foi isto, ainda bem que ele pode reverter :)

Comment: @bigown O wiki foi totalmente sem querer. Qual ao tratamento de exceções, entendo o problema e agradeço a observação. Não sei se resolve, mas acrescentei alguns comentários e observações na resposta .

Comment: @utluiz sim, foram colocados pontos importantes. Fica mais claro que a solução não é definitiva, é um exemplo base para iniciar.

Answer (score 6):

Eu vou responder as suas perguntas fazendo primeiro uma analogia com a vida real, depois comentando os três pontos que você levantou:

Imagine que você é um funcionário de uma indústria e o seu chefe direto solicita que você vá até uma loja e compre determinado produto (digamos, a matéria prima). Você pega o carro e chega nessa loja as 12hrs e para sua surpresa a loja encontra-se fechada. Nesse momento **você percebe que ocorreu uma exceção**<sup>1</sup> uma vez que a loja sempre abre das 8h as 18h (todos os dias). Mas você fará de tudo para evitar maiores problemas e então pensa: **Vou esperar 30 minutos, as vezes o vendedor saiu para almoçar e já esta voltando**<sup>2</sup>. Você sai para dar uma volta e 30 minutos depois você volta e **percebe que a loja continua fechada.**<sup>3</sup> - Como você não tem mais nenhum indicio de que a loja reabrirá você percebe que você não tem mais nenhuma opção já que a única loja que você é autorizado a comprar é aquela.

Você então volta para a indústria e **comunica o seu chefe direto**<sup>4</sup>. O seu chefe direto estranhando a situação **registra que houve aquele problema para futuras auditorias**<sup>5</sup> e **comunica o dono da empresa**<sup>6</sup>. O dono da empresa imediatamente **solicita que ao seu chefe o envie a uma segunda loja**<sup>7</sup>, você prontamente atende a solicitação e dessa vez **consegue realizar a compra com sucesso.**<sup>8</sup>

#### Moral da História

Nem sempre existe um mecanismo de tratar exceções - por exemplo, após tentar um número limitado de vezes você pode concluir que seus recursos se esgotaram para tratar aquela exceção e que por isso o mais correto a fazer é notificar quem te solicitou - repassar a exceção - dizendo: *eu tentei, mas por causa disso ... eu não consegui*.

Quando você lança uma exceção você esta basicamente "repassando o problema ao seu chefe". O seu chefe pode ter uma solução para cada tipo de problema. Na analogia apresentada o chefe falou com o dono da empresa pois ele também não tinha mais nenhuma saída para o `LojaFechadaException`. Talvez se a exceção fosse `PrecoAcimaDaMediaException` seu próprio chefe pudesse resolver o problema sem repassar para o dono da empresa. *É por isso que é importante ter exceções específicas e que portanto é ruim generaliza-las.*

O fato é; se a exceção chegasse no dono da empresa e nem ele tivesse uma saída, uma estratégia de contorno, ele não poderia fazer nada além de registrar o ocorrido para futuras referencias: o famoso senta e chora.

#### Explicando a Analogia (compare com os números no texto)

1- Você percebe que foi lançada uma exceção
2- Você tem uma estratégia para contornar a exceção
3- A sua estratégia não funcionou, você vai lançar a exceção para alguém tratar
4- Quem invocou o seu método é notificado da exceção (o `catch` é invocado)
5- Também não há o que ser feito - apenas é registrado no log de erros
6- Você repassa novamente a exceção para um nível ainda maior
7- O último nível tem um outro mecanismo para tratar a exceção que ocorreu lá na ponta
8- A tarefa é executada com sucesso e o usuário fica feliz

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** Se nem sequer o último nível soubesse tratar a exceção o que acontece normalmente é o seu programa finalizar com código diferente de zero, ou um não-sucesso.

#### Respondendo suas perguntas

1- O tratamento que você deu pode ser o tratamento adequado. Eu desconheço o contexto do seu programa. Se imprimir o log no console for de fato a sua última instância então porque isto estaria errado? Eu apenas sugiro que você use um mecanismo mais interessante para registrar esse log (fora do escopo da resposta)

2- Sim. Se isto é o melhor que você pode fazer e não lhe resta mais nenhuma opção antes de exibir o erro para o usuário, então este é um tratamento de exceção sim - você inclusive impediu que seu programa terminasse.

3- Você só estaria dando trabalho ao seu usuário. Na verdade essa é mais uma questão de usabilidade do que de tratamento de exceção.