# Retornar Conexão como Boolean?

Tags: java, jdbc

Seria possível de modificar a classe para que ela retorne para jFrame o resultado da conexão como boolean?

```
public class ConectarDB {

    private static Connection con = null;

    public static Connection getConexao() {

        // Drive do PostGreSQL
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }

        // Variáveis de Conexão
        String drive    = "jdbc:postgresql";
        String ip   = "localhost";
        String port     = "5432";
        String db   = "basedados";
        String user     = "postgres";
        String password = "senha";
        String conexao  = drive + "://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + db;

        // Conectar-se ao Banco de Dados
        try {
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, user, password);        
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível se conectar ao Banco de Dados!", "Aviso!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        // Retorno da Informação
        return con;

    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        getConexao();
    }

}
```

Retorno para validar

```
if(netResultado.equals(false)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sem conexão com a Internet.", "Informação", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else if(dbResultado.equals(false)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sem conexão com o Banco de Dadost.", "Informação", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else if(netResultado.equals(true)) {
```

Comment: `boolean testeConexao = con.isValid(5);`

Comment: Olá, Eduardo. Onde posso colocar essa linha de comando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso

public class ConectarDB {

```
private static Connection con = null;

public static boolean getConexao() {

    // Drive do PostGreSQL
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }

    // Variáveis de Conexão
    String drive    = "jdbc:postgresql";
    String ip   = "localhost";
    String port     = "5432";
    String db   = "basedados";
    String user     = "postgres";
    String password = "senha";
    String conexao  = drive + "://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + db;

    // Conectar-se ao Banco de Dados
    try {
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(conexao, user, password);
       return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível se conectar ao Banco de Dados!", "Aviso!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    // Retorno da Informação


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getConexao();
}
```

}

Comment: Funciona. Só não vai funcionar para o que eu preciso. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Você precisa exatamente pra que? Se puder falar posso ajudar.

Comment: Caso a conexão tenha dado erro quando retornar para JFrame principal ele informar que houve um erro. Não queria deixar a mensagem de erro nessa janela. Se eu mudar para boolean afeta um monte de coisa no meu projeto. Obrigado!! OBS: Foi adicionado código no inicio da página.

Comment: Não entendi direito ainda, mas se sua dúvida é exibir o erro apenas lá naquele segundo trecho de código que vc colocou, sugiro o uso da palavra-chave **throws** na declaração de getConexao(), o throws basicamente diz que vc deve capturar uma possível exceção na chamada do método e dessa maneira vc não é obrigado a capturar o erro na implementação do método. [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17025/usando-as-palavras-chave-throws-e-throw]

Comment: Não tive erro com relação ao código mais tenho classes que precisa da conexão e está dando erro porque agora é Boolean entende? Mais tem problema não. Obrigado!